# Provide a setting to hide "Featured on Meta" posts in the Community Bulletin

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, meta, community-bulletin

Please provide an option to hide **just Meta posts** in the Community Bulletin from me. I still want to see [Stack Overflow Blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/) posts though, because I want to stay up-to-date on new features and stuff.

Jeff was right. [Meta Is Murder](http://blog.codinghorror.com/meta-is-murder/). I've decided that I don't really want to participate in Meta all that much. It's not really what I want to do with my time. I'd rather spend that time answering Git questions on Stack Overflow instead.

The problem is, the Community Bulletin is in my face.

[image: Homepage]

All the time.

[image: Git tag]

I can't escape it.

[image]

Comment: Time to develop some banner blindness.

Comment: For this purpose we have user stylesheets. :)

Comment: Put a post-it note on your screen with your own content: "milk, eggs, butter, bread, beer"

Comment: @ShadowWizard you mean Chrome stylesheets? I thought the Chrome team removed that a while back?

Comment: Adblock will do it.

Comment: @Cupcake: Seriously? And I thought Chrome couldn't possibly get *any less* user-friendly.

Comment: @BoltClock [Issue 318566: User Stylesheets removal breaks all DevTools themes](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=318566). I'm surprised people haven't noticed. This broke my dark-theme Chrome developer tools several months back `:P`

Comment: @Cupcake good point! So what about https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylebot/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha?hl=en for Chrome?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I greatly distrust 3rd-party Chrome extensions, [which may end up containing malware in the future, without warning](http://arstechnica.com/security/2014/01/malware-vendors-buy-chrome-extensions-to-send-adware-filled-updates/).

Comment: So custom userscript is the last resort, I fear. I might write one if I'll have some time, hope you'll trust it's malware free. :D

Comment: So I'm not sure, is this question getting downvotes because people disagree with the usefulness of my feature request, or is it getting downvotes because the request is somehow poorly written?

Comment: I agree whole-heartedly with this request. Ever since the move to a dedicated Meta for SE, the community bulletin has been going nuts! I don't know if it's because the move drew a lot of attention, or something was changed when Meta.SO became SO-only. But there's almost always some new meta post that I click on without thinking, and it's inevitably a wordy complaint that's then simultaneously apologized for and dismissed wordily in the answers. Despite this, I clearly can't be trained not to click on the links; they have to go.

Comment: @anthony-arnold "[Why is Stack Overflow so negative of late?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251758/456814)". With click-bait like that, how could anyone resist? `:P`

Comment: @ShadowWizard I'm interest in the user script! Or just to know what I should put in the Stylist extension for Chrome, I tried community-bulletin without success (hot-network-questions works)

Comment: @lib cheers, see my answer. :)

Comment: @lib I wrote a [userscript](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268587/3366929) if you still want it.

Comment: Just for irony: http://i.stack.imgur.com/bOX5u.png

Answer (score 18):

There is no escape from meta.

It will find you.

It a̳lwà̝͉ys f̖ị̧͙͓ṉ̼͓̭d̪͇͖̤s͙̰̻̭͖͍͢ y̸ͅo̡̜̬̣̘͢͡u͔̘͘͝.̡̨͎̰͇̭̠̕.̙̮̭͇̣̘̬.̘̜̤̤̙̥̰̱̼

#### See also: [Can the threshold for what makes it into the Community Bulletin be raised?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252465/can-the-watermark-for-the-community-bulletin-be-raised)

Comment: Cute. `:P` [Zalgo](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/zalgo) haunts the halls of Meta, leading the unwary to [the dark side](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/456814) `:P`

Comment: Just for the record, Cupcake disapproves `:P`

Answer (score 12):

As a dirty hack, you can download browser extension that let you define a custom style, e.g. [Stylish](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe?hl=en) for Chrome, then add such CSS rule for Stack Overflow:

```css
.s-sidebarwidget a[href^='http://meta.'] { display: none; }
```

This will effectively hide all the links pointing to the per site meta, though leaving the placeholder. If CSS guru can come with a way to hide the placeholder as well I'll be grateful.

Comment: In my previous attempts I got to hide completely the side column, this is much better!

Comment: adblock plus too

Comment: i tried this, it doesn't seem to work. is there a change in the website?

Comment: @tinker thanks, they changed the CSS a lot over the years, yes. I've updated the answer, it might also hide more links in the side bar though as they don't give any special class to community bulletin anymore, and I didn't check it deeply. Let me know if the new code cause any problem.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, please! For *exactly* the same reasons: I am getting sucked in to Meta conversations. I'd rather be answering Stack Overflow questions than commenting on why the quality of Stack Overflow is going downhill.

Most galling is that my Meta posts are getting more votes than my tech answers.

(Second most likely thing to suck me in is "Hot Network Questions". I get to discover boards I didn't even know existed. It is fascinating, but distracting. On reflection, if I could customize the side panel I think I'd choose to hide both Meta and Hot Network Questions).

Answer (score 5):

Running with Shadow Wizard's answer a bit, and running with it:

- first, install Stylish add-on, available for at least Chrome and Firefox (I'm using Firefox, https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/ )
- then click the new 'S' button that appears, do 'Write new style' | 'for stackoverflow.com', and add the following text into the `{ }` pair that appear:

`#hot-network-questions { display: none; }
.community-bulletin { display: none; }`

Bingo! No more hot network questions, or community bulletin :-)

Comment: Further, someone has written a style for you called https://userstyles.org/styles/146704/undistractify-stackoverflow-enhanced "undistractify stackoverflow enhanced".  Works well.  Upvoting.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a little late here, but I've written a [userscript](https://stackapps.com/questions/4844/hide-the-community-bulletin) that does exactly what you've described.

I'm placing it here delicately with a warning: Shog9 says that Meta participation from main-site users [has been on the rise](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268240/what-does-meta-police-mean/268244?noredirect=1#comment75421_268244), and I'd hate to stop that growth because I think that it's crucial for people who use the site to direct its progress.

However, you're already here, so that shouldn't be much of a problem: use it wisely.

It removes links to per-site metas on the Community Bulletin and will only show blog posts/podcasts/featured Meta.SE posts/anything Stack Exchange puts in the bulletin that points to something other than a per-site meta.

If the bulletin only contains links to a per-site meta, it is not shown at all.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way to achieve this: Get [this Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/custom-javascript-for-web/ddbjnfjiigjmcpcpkmhogomapikjbjdk?hl=en) ([here's the github repo](https://github.com/xcv58/Custom-JavaScript-for-Websites-2)), and use it to execute this code on every page load:

```
document.querySelector("#sidebar > div:first-child").remove();
```

To hide other annoying elements,

```
var hiring = document.getElementById("hireme");
var meta = document.getElementById("sidebar").children[1];
var hot_network_qs = document.getElementById("hot-network-questions");
var chat = document.getElementById("chat-feature");

if (hiring) {
    hiring.parentNode.removeChild(hiring);
}
if (meta) {
    meta.parentNode.removeChild(meta);
}
if (hot_network_qs) {
    hot_network_qs.parentNode.removeChild(hot_network_qs);
}
if (chat) {
    chat.parentNode.removeChild(chat);
}
```