# Can the threshold for what makes it into the Community Bulletin be raised?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, community-bulletin

Related to [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251920/provide-a-setting-to-hide-meta-posts-in-the-community-bulletin), which didn't really seem to get much support.

Still, because the meta community for Stack Overflow is so active, whatever tool decides which questions are noteworthy enough to be posted on the community bulletin seems to have a hard time coping with the number of high-scoring questions.

I always check the community bulletin to see if there's a new blog post or podcast. But I really only expect the meta posts which end up there to be *really* important. Like, if something's being discussed which would mean a moderate-to-major change in the site. I really don't think that [a question about tag synonyms for a little-used tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252329/reliable-is-a-synonym-of-reliability?cb=1) are worth posting *at the top of every page*.

Answer (score 20):

First off, yes: it can be raised. Right now, the "watermark" is 3:

> ...the rest of the space is filled with hot discussion questions not marked status-completed, scoring at least 3 and posted within the past two weeks. These are picked semi-randomly. At least one of these will always be added to the list, even if it pushes the length over 4.

That's from [How is the contents of the Community Bulletin determined?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130621/how-is-the-contents-of-the-community-bulletin-determined/130893#130893), which lists the rest of the criteria as well. But that one paragraph is all that's really necessary for *this* discussion. That, and one other tidbit...

**The list refreshes every 20 minutes.**

That, combined, with the semi-random nature by which meta posts are picked, goes a long way toward keeping boring topics from monopolizing the list: they'll get their 20 minutes of fame, but after that something else will come up, thereby helping casual readers gain an idea of *what meta is for* without having to camp on the front page [like some pathetic loser](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9).

I'm not against raising the watermark *a little bit*. But I don't want it to be so high that the list becomes static, the same 3-4 posts picked every time. *That* really gets old fast. And so I've been giving it a bit of time just to see how much traffic meta gets in the space of two weeks of normal activity.

I actually think tag *discussions* are pretty important, particularly those able to garner more than a few votes. Things like [burninate-request](/questions/tagged/burninate-request) in particular are worth getting a broader range of opinions on before implementing.

But there's a lot of other important stuff being discussed here too: proposed features, crucial support issues, even one or two bugs. And let's face it: even the general-interest discussions don't really need *two weeks* in the spotlight.

So, for Meta Stack Overflow *only*, **we'll now be featuring *all* hot meta questions scoring 3 or more in the bulletin.** And we'll exclude those more than 3 days old, to keep it fresh. As before, the list will be chosen randomly every 20 minutes or thereabouts from the pool of eligible questions.

Hopefully, these changes will make things a bit less boring.

Comment: Would tagging things with no-community-bulletin and adding a filter for it be out of the question (more relevant to keeping depressing recurring "doom, doom and noobs everywhere" themes from monopolising the list)?

Comment: Oded is stating the code [caches the CB for 1 hour](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236687/per-site-hot-meta-questions-are-still-hot-after-being-deleted?noredirect=1#comment827710_236687), not 20 minutes. I'm trying to confirm his assertion now by observing the CB.

Comment: Oded is correct, @Martijn - I was going from memory, and I guess my memory of 3-year-old discussions isn't as great as I'd hope.

Comment: @Shog9: so you want to update this meta post or shall I? :-)