# How are question on meta added to the Community Bulletin

Tags: support, community-bulletin

I'm wondering about questions on the **Community Bulletin**.

How are these questions picked? What is the standard?

Does the community play a role in picking questions to be added to the Community Bulletin, or it is just a moderator option?

Comment: [How are the contents of the Community Bulletin determined?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/130621)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Community Bulletin shows links to pages related to:

- Moderator elections
- Events (added by moderators and select Stack Exchange employees)
- Blog posts
- [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) meta posts
- Hot MSO questions which are *not* tagged as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

There will always be at least 4 links, selected in the priority listed above.

Complete details are available at: [How are the contents of the Community Bulletin determined?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130621/how-are-the-contents-of-the-community-bulletin-determined)

**For Meta Stack Overflow only**, the bulletin will contain all hot meta questions scoring 3 or more. It will exclude those more than 3 days old, to keep it fresh. As before, the list will be chosen randomly every 20 minutes or thereabouts from the pool of eligible questions. Reference: [Shog's post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252467/).