# What are the requirements of a question for it to end up on the hot meta posts section?

Tags: support, hot-questions, community-bulletin

How are they chosen?

Are there any specific requirements?

Are any questions missed off?

[image]

Comment: Is there anyway to directly dupe it to: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/257978/how-are-question-on-meta-added-to-the-community-bulletin instead or does that not matter?

Comment: I sometimes prefer to (vote to) close a question as a dupe of another post, which itself is already closed as a dupe. That way you are able to read both questions and its answers. But I only do that if the existing answer of the other closed question could be useful as well.

Comment: @Tom I just asked this, feel free the post an answer: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381784/should-duplicate-questions-be-linked-to-the-original-question-or-any-duplicate-q