# Can a controversial question be considered a "hot question"?

Tags: discussion, questions, meta, hot-questions

I see the "Hot Meta Post" sidebar, and I notice that they are often high voted questions. I asked in the meta chat but nobody got back to me so:

Can a controversial question (many up/downvotes) be considered a hot meta post?

It would require many upvotes so that it's not just a bad question in general, but something people both agree and disagree on.

Comment: This question is currently at +3 (+7/-4) and is listed in "Hot Meta Posts" ;)

Comment: And your question heading hot meta posts now :)

Comment: Ha, oh the irony.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Meta can see a lot of voting in either direction; a controversial post is most definitely hot in that it is attracting a lot of attention.

That can happen with discussions, some issues divide. When that happens there is no reason to shun such posts from the the community bulletin.

[Criteria for 'hot' meta posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130621/how-are-the-contents-of-the-community-bulletin-determined) are otherwise quite simple:

- <strike>Tagged `discussion`</strike>
- *Not* tagged [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
- Scoring 3 or more.
- No more than <strike>2 weeks</strike> *3 days* old.

So even a post with 50 upvotes and 43 downvotes qualifies; it is still scoring +3 or more.

Note that these rules are [specific to Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252465/can-the-threshold-for-what-makes-it-into-the-community-bulletin-be-raised/252467#252467); other Meta sites require the post to be tagged [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discussion) and allow for posts up to two weeks old to be shown.

Comment: Nonono, I didn't mean shun them, I just never really see them. I usually only see pure upvoted questions, not border line +7 with 50 up and 43 down

Comment: @SterlingArcher: the criteria are really not that strict; added them to the post.

Comment: One should maybe add that if there are more posts than slots that qualify then the ones shown are chosen semi-randomly (whatever that means).

Comment: @Trilarion: probably a weighted random picking more recent / higher scoring posts more often.

Comment: The fact that a question has to have a score of at least 3 does make the Community Bulletin *a little biased* though, in my opinion, especially considering the [confusing and haphazard voting practices on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254108/456814). Even if a question is a well-written, neutral non-rant, all it takes is a few downvotes from people who merely disagree, and the question has a high chance of never being seen outside of those first few voters, because it never gets circulation in the bulletin. That problem has been talked about before in other questions too.

Comment: @Cupcake: This very question has been bouncing around 0 for a while and made it to the CB anyway. There are plenty of us that look at posts directly here on meta without the CB pulling us in.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Is the first bullet of your answer still valid in light of this post: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268577/

Comment: @AzizShaikh: thanks for the heads-up; yes, this post was outdated.

Comment: @MartijnPieters you are welcome. Was the change done on MSO only or across the board?

Comment: @AzizShaikh: MSO only.