# Why do feature-requests and support questions appear in the community bulletin?

Tags: support, community-bulletin

According to [How are the contents of the Community Bulletin determined?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130621/how-are-the-contents-of-the-community-bulletin-determined/130893#130893):

> - If there are still fewer than 4 items listed, then **[featured](/questions/tagged/featured) meta posts** are shown (only those scoring 0 or above).
> - If there are still under 4 items, the rest of the space is filled with **hot [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) questions** not marked
>     [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), scoring at least 3 and posted within the
>     past two weeks. These are picked semi-randomly. At least *one* of
>     these will always be added to the list, even if it pushes the length
>     over 4.

However, I've been observing this isn't how it works (but the only place I can reproduce this behavior is on Stack Overflow):

> [image: Community Bulletin]

Two of the questions are [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) questions, but one is a [support](/questions/tagged/support) question and the other is a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request).

Is this a bug? Or is this just how the bulletin works, and the post I've linked to is wrong?

Comment: I vote that this should be automatically featured in the community bulletin... *(I placed the 3rd upvote)*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [Can the threshold for what makes it into the Community Bulletin be raised?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252465/can-the-threshold-for-what-makes-it-into-the-community-bulletin-be-raised/252467#252467):

> So, for Meta Stack Overflow *only*, **we'll now be featuring all hot meta questions scoring 3 or more in the bulletin**. And we'll exclude those more than 3 days old, to keep it fresh. As before, the list will be chosen randomly every 20 minutes or thereabouts from the pool of eligible questions.

Comment: My only question is: why are we featuring [meta-tag:support] and [meta-tag:bug] reports? Sure, it's great to have the community talk about [meta-tag:discussion] questions and [meta-tag:feature-request]... but [meta-tag:support] questions and [meta-tag:bug] reports?

Comment: Why not? Support requests are often of interest to multiple people, particularly when topical. Bug reports can be of interest for the same reason. And with such a large pool to draw from and a 3-day window, there's less chance that folks will get sick of them.

Comment: If the site's logo all of a sudden has a typo in it because of a drunk designer, chances are people are going to notice and want to report it. If it's in the side, most will know right away that it's already brought to the dev's attention and thus can upvote it and bring it more attention. Meta votes are very commonly a good sign of urgency in regards to bug reports.

Comment: A quick note: this site-specific override was removed when Hot Meta Posts was reinstated on this site. It's now at the network-wise default, which as of the beginning of this month includes only discussions and feature requests.