# How are the "Hot Meta Posts" calculated?

Tags: discussion, community-bulletin

Currently the "Hot Meta Posts" are:

[image: hot meta posts]

How are these calculated? Why are posts like [this pretty hot post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370792/is-this-really-what-we-should-consider-unwelcoming) not included?

[image: is this really]

Comment: see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268577/578411\

Comment: A wooden, cubic AI patterned with dots does the job.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to shog9's answer [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268577/5389107) (also mentioned by rene in his comment), the list is chosen at random every 20 minutes from all posts that fulfill the criteria:

> So, for Meta Stack Overflow only, we'll now be featuring all hot meta questions scoring 3 or more in the bulletin. And we'll exclude those more than 3 days old, to keep it fresh. As before, the list will be chosen randomly every 20 minutes or thereabouts from the pool of eligible questions.

This means that the question you linked may be eligible but just wasn't chosen in the random rotation occuring every 20 minutes this time.

Comment: I didn't write that as an answer because it is a partial answer. It doesn't define what a *hot* meta question is. And all we know is that the hotness algorithm is a trade secret.

Comment: @rene In my mind, a partial answer is better then no answer at all and just a comment. At least more discoverable.

Comment: We also use a geiger counter and a thermometer. It's a contraption Shog built himself out of an old Mr. Popcorn machine. It's also got like 72 lasers on it.

Comment: Only 72 lasers?