# How are hot meta posts ordered?

Tags: discussion, support, community-bulletin

I know how the hot meta posts are calculated - *[How are the "Hot Meta Posts" calculated?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370963/how-are-the-hot-meta-posts-calculated)*. But how are they ordered?

When I view hot meta posts on SO, they are ordered like this:

[image]

But on MSO, they are ordered like this:

[image]

Why are they differently ordered, and how are they ordered?

Comment: Looks like they are both aligned left to me.

Comment: It could be random....

Comment: Hmm, it's the same order every time... (unless the item changes)

Comment: That list is cached, it obv doesn't change every time you reload the page.