# Is it relatively easy to get answer badges on Meta?

Tags: discussion, badges, meta

So I got another [Nice Answer badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/23/nice-answer) for one of my answers.

This got me thinking: I have answered [only 4 times on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1461424/krumia?tab=answers), and it yielded two Nice Answer badges. Whereas on Stack Overflow, I have [only 1 Nice Answer badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/23/nice-answer?userid=1461424) for [81 answers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1461424/krumia?tab=answers) (to be honest not all of them are of outstanding quality).

While I am impressed with myself for my achievements on Meta, I have a feeling that it is relatively easy to achieve an answer badge on Meta. This *feeling* can be confirmed if someone can come up with statistics for "upvotes per answer" per "views per question". (English: Get the number of upvotes of the answer, and divide it by the number of views for the relevant question. Do this for every answer, then average. Do everything above for MSO and SO, and then compare).

Or is there another more suitable metric to answer this question?

Comment: FWIW the easiest gold badge at MSO seems to be [Reversal](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/57/reversal). One only needs to pick an unpopular question and trash it more or less thoroughly in the answer

Comment: Posting in a [meta-tag:featured] question also tends to net lots of votes one way or the other. Meta questions can also benefit from the Hot Meta Posts window.

Comment: I believe folks that hang here are much more vote-prone than on the main site.

Comment: @JonK But only moderators can use the (featured) tag, so if one takes this road to badges, the first step is to get elected a moderator (or hired by SE). Not that easy.

Comment: @Thursday I wasn't suggesting that you could post a featured question - just that you could post **in** one. We've had three of them recently, so you wouldn't have to wait all that long for another one to pop up.

Comment: Yes, if you care about shiny badges, they are much easier to come by on Meta. From looking at my list, I seem to have about 5 silver and 7 bronze badges that are answer related on Meta, from 19 answers. On the main site, I got 1 silver and 1 bronze from 374 answers. If that's any indication, it's about 100 times easier on Meta.

Comment: @AstroCB: Thanks for the edit. Yes I shouldn't have added the link in the first place :)

Comment: @Krumia It's just a thought (reading it over, the summary may be a bit harsh: you can rollback the edit if you want to).

Comment: @AstroCB: No. Now the question is impartial because of the way you have edited it.

Comment: I have the same feeling. I have 326 answers in StackOverflow (a lot of them nice quality) and I have no **Nice Answer** badge yet. It depends a lot of the tags you answer, too.

Comment: funny example - Reversal badge on... self-answer: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276440/remove-rep-loss-when-down-voting-with-a-comment

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are *far fewer new posts* each day on Meta and many posts affect everyone; that translates to more eyeballs per post than an answer in a specialist subject on Stack Overflow will attract.

That is quite apart from the extra attention afforded to hot questions ([score 3 or up, no older than 3 days](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252467/100297)) that are featured on just about all pages on Stack Overflow in the community bulletin.

Ergo, with more views, you get more votes per post and badges are easier to earn.

Comment: I think brasofilo is onto something with his comment, too. The people who read Meta regularly are the experienced users who understand how the site works, and they therefore *vote*. There are still a lot of users on the main site who avoid voting for unknown reasons.

Comment: @Cody: that may well be a smaller group than you think it is; just compare view counts on Meta versus posts on Stack Overflow 1 hour after posting. Meta posts consistently have higher view counts.

Comment: @MartijnPieters The view count is for "unique viewers"? As of myself, I tend to revisit frequently meta questions of interest to read new comments and/or answers. But I do that rarely on the main site.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux: not quite, see [How are the number of views in a question calculated?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/36728).

Answer (score 2):

Participatory democracy works better on meta than on SO.

By clicking on the question/answer score, you will see that the displayed score is usually the result of a more balanced votes. Maybe this is only caused by the fact questions here are often "opinion based" ?

Anyway, we are definitively prompt to vote here. And to share our opinion, as you can see by the usually high number of comments!

Comment: Part of the reason that it works better is because Meta is smaller—in terms of question volume, that is. I can log in every day or so for an hour or two and read/interact with *all* of the questions. That's impossible on Stack Overflow, even when I just monitor a dozen tags or so. It's the same reason that local democratic governments are often more effective (at being democratic) than federal democratic governments.

Comment: @CodyGray Maybe this is only a coincidence: but I really feel like votes on MSO are more "balanced" (i.e.: a mix of up- and down-votes) than on the main site, where votes <strike>tends</strike> _seems_ to be more uniform (only up- or only down-votes). Still about my "feeling", I think that votes on MSO are really a way to tell "I agree/I don't agree", whereas is SO votes are more often "value-judgments" based on the post quality (on the occasion triggering an "emotional reaction" from the poster). But maybe you are right, this is only the "number effect" that distorts my perceptions...