# Remove rep loss when downvoting with a comment

Tags: feature-request, reputation, downvotes

<sup><sub>No, I'm not suggesting this be the case... just every time I see it come up, I can't find the duplicate to flag because it was deleted voluntarily.</sub></sup>

It's annoying to lose reputation when you downvote an answer. And people keep asking why the downvote. Let's kill two birds with one stone and make it so that if there is a comment by the voter, it doesn't cost anything to downvote.

Answer (score 28):

Let us consider the types of comments that this would allow for:

> - -1 comment to avoid -1 rep. -SomeUser
> - -1 comment to avoid -1 rep... because upvotes on other comments don't count. -OtherUser
> - I like ponies. -Bob
> - -1 I like ponies too.  -Will
> - <del>Some deleted comment. -SnarkyUser</del>
> - <del>F* This. -ObsceneUser</del> (deleted by mod)

The problem with this, and many 'encourage comments in association with votes' suggestions is that they make no guarantees about the *quality* of that information.

Comments already have a low enough signal to noise ratio.  People try to figure out [how to show fewer comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204402/213963)... and its a hard problem.  Encouraging pointless comments (see above) makes this an even harder problem to solve while at the same time not providing any good feedback to the OP who is getting down voted (they'll likely think that Stack Overflow is full of negative snarky elitists... and I shouldn't need to link that text).

Further consider that reputation loss from down voting answers is already refunded - if the answer is deleted.  This then leads us to a number of "do we refund the rep" situations and ugly business logic:

- How long between comment and vote (before? after?) for a refund?
- What happens if a comment is deleted by the user? by a mod? by flags?
- What happens when the answer is deleted and the reputation is already refunded (yes, that should be obvious... but start thinking about the logic)
- What happens if a down vote is reversed? through a serial down vote detection?
- Does a comment from a custom close message count?

All of this makes it a complete mess to try to have a way to refund down votes.  Instead, consider down votes as an investment in the quality of the site - they help filter good posts from poor posts, provide signal into the low quality rate limits and low quality review queue.  And if the post is some day deleted, the reputation is refunded.

Additional, leaving comments as they are rather than encouraging additional noise and snark in the system is likely a good thing.   Users can leave comments and down vote if they want, or not.  Comments themselves are "second class citizens" in many parts of the site design that are intended for more transient information (such as clarifications and improvements) that *should* find their way the body of the post.  While the clarification comments *could* be such, they may also *not* be clarifications and thus additional unintended use of comments *should* be avoided.

I will also point out the 'down vote witch hunts' that sometimes go on.  Having someone comment and then someone else anonymously down vote would can lead to incorrect reprisals (not that one should ever attempt to down vote for reprisals) - this doesn't need to be encouraged by giving the suggestion that down votes come from commenters.

Related MSE posts:

- [Penalise Downvotes without Comment / Reward Downvotes with Comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59736/penalise-downvotes-without-comment-reward-downvotes-with-comments)
- [Make it cost more to down vote without comment; make it hurt to leave a crap comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134836/make-it-cost-more-to-downvote-without-comment-make-it-hurt-to-leave-a-crap-comm)
- [Have downvotes cost more, to be refunded when a comment on that question/answer gets an upvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35347/have-downvotes-cost-more-to-be-refunded-when-a-comment-on-that-question-answer)

Comment: Well presented/argued.  I would add that comments are by intention a peripheral part of the site, often useful only in a transient way for clarifications and other improvements that eventually find a lasting place in edits to Questions and Answers.

Comment: @hardmath I've added some of the intent you have there into the latest post (and community wiki'ed it too).  If you have other material, feel free to add it.

Comment: Thats interesting, is it possible to get Reversal for self answer?

Comment: @nicael [yes](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/57/reversal?userid=289086).

Comment: "-1 comment to avoid down vote." - in this case you at least know that this downvote is baseless. It is much better than not knowing why you are downvoted.

Comment: The point made and the possible misuse is well laid out. BUT it is all in all a very negative view on things, where the validity of the question is challenged. It is possible to make equally negative points about the status quo with downvoting. And as such, I see it as a rhetorical trick instead of a sincere attempt to help find something better.