# Why is downvoting on Stack Overflow that cheap?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, downvotes, voting

I agree with the downvoting system; people should express always their opinion in some way.

Now, my concern is basically, why is it so cheap to downvote questions where people has wasted their time?

As far as I know only 1 point is subtracted from your own reputation if you want to downvote. My question is, why is only -1? Sometimes it is really annoying to see people downvoting without even explaining the reasons.

It's obviously true many questions are not following the Stack Overflow guidelines or they are just very low quality. But in my opinion, I'd prefer if someone thinks such questions are that bad they should pay a little bit more for the "right" to say so **or** at least pointing out why they think the questions are bad in order to improve the quality of the questions.

Comment: Downvotes on questions don't cost any reputation. Only those on answers.

Comment: Why are upvotes so cheap?  Downvotes on answers are are *infinitely* more expensive than upvotes.

Comment: As for why? Because we encourage downvotes and found that if they do have a high cost people don't downvote. Meaning that our first and best signal for problem posts will be greatly diluted to the detriment of the site.

Comment: So your feature request is to have downvotes on question cost *something* rather than *nothing*?

Comment: We have done the whole downvote explanation debate ad nauseam. Before you go down that route, read up on some of the previous discussions.

Comment: @Oded: I've commented on the Servy's answer my reasons about posting this bad accepted (i don't know why as usual) question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove rep loss when down voting with a comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276440/remove-rep-loss-when-down-voting-with-a-comment)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Why is it so cheap?  Honestly, I'd ask why it's so expensive.  But to answer the question of why it's not *more* expensive, it's because *we want people to actually use them*.  If you increase the cost of downvotes, people won't use them, which means bad content won't get downvoted, which means people won't be able to see what content is bad.  It would also prevent serially bad contributors from having consequences to their harmful behavior, such as behing rate limited or blocked, it would inhibit the deletion of harmful content, and remove the dis-incentives for those contributing harmful content from continuing to do so, and remove the incentives to improve their contributions.

Comment: Servy Here's a little of background why I'm asking this... my experience with SO site hasn't been good so far. I haven't had any problem providing answers mostly all the time to people if I decide to put some effort on my answers. Now, my experience asking questions has been quite the opposite. SO community hasn't helped me almost 50% of the time even when I boutied, 7 out of my 12 questions have had really a bad acception.

Comment: Servy In conclusion: I'm not asking people any answers if my questions are that hard for them. But at least, some comments about improving my "low-quality" questions would be less rude & cheap than downvoting them directly using anonymity, which is just lame IMHO

Comment: @BPL methinks this is the time where you take a breather and turn your thoughts around with some meta searches. Starting with researching into why exactly downvotes are anonymous. Its very enlightening material that makes it easier to accept that no it is in fact not lame, quite the opposite.

Comment: @BPL How would changing the reputation cost affect that in any way?  Getting people to stop downvoting bad questions would just make those bad questions much harder to distinguish from those that are worth one's time.  It wouldn't actually make the questions any better, or help the authors fix them any more; in fact, it would be worse, as they would be that much less likely to even know that they were doing something wrong.  Just knowing that your questions are consistently not up to standard is enough to tell you to start looking through the help center, and other related resources.

Comment: @Gimby Sure, I'll try to read more about this subject. Now, here's a little example of (IMHO) [good proactive behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39060756/how-to-hide-ttk-treeitem-indicators-in-a-python-gui/39259113?noredirect=1#39259113). Short story, I had downvoted the answer of this guy cos his solution wasn't working for me, he asked why the downvote so I explained him my reason. Conclusion was: he improved his answer considerably and I've upvoted him again. That's what I'd expect from nice proactive people.

Comment: @bpl and if I downvoted one of your questions/answers I would lend you the same courtesy, because I know you react reasonable. But there are plenty of cases where I decide to not comment at all, because it'd be the same as poking a bee hive.

Comment: @Servy So, what's the solution then? As I said, mostly of my questions were badly received and I think they aren't that bad questions. Little bit hard? That's relative, but maybe. Too broad? Maybe. Non excellent usage of english? Probably... Low quality questions for not even realizing **what's so wrong with them**? I don't think so

Comment: @BPL Other people aren't obligated to fix your questions for you.  At the end of the day it is *your* responsibility to ask an acceptable question.  If someone chooses to take time out of their day to help you out, that's great, but not *expected* of them.

Comment: @Servy That's a really valid point! problem appears when my opinion of asking a "right" question is pretty much different from anonym downvoter's opinion very often. In any case, I hope I'll become much better asking questions according to people's expectations and start receiving answers, otherwise the experience is just frustrating and my opinion of SO is becoming like a place where only trivial stuff can be asked&solved

Comment: @Gimby Lol, poking a bee hive, I'll make that expression mine from now on ;D , +1

Comment: @BPL - you can always ask for feedback on "specific-question" how to improve it. Also I'd reiterate Gimby's comment - make sure to search for similar requests on META first - it is often the same set of issues - asking for recommendations, no demonstrated research, lack of MCVE...

Answer (score 8):

> mostly of my questions were badly received and I think they aren't that bad questions.

Let's test that theory.

Here's a list of every question you've asked which you have not accepted an answer for:

- [How to avoid being crawled/penalized by google](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39270481/734069)

  *Way* too broad.
- [How to make a fast lightweight mobile friendly django website?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39257162/734069)

  A classic "do my work for me" question.
- [how to know more about built-in modules](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39209131/734069)

  A reasonable question, for which you got an answer. And zero downvotes.
- [how can i display hierarchical data using django & js?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39193381/734069)

  Another "do my work for me" question.
- [How to design a nodegraph widget which contains subgraphs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38987494/734069)

  This question is more appropriate for Code Review, since you're primarily asking about the quality of your code.
- [3ds Max plugin which exports steps to generate the scene](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38942033/734069)

  More "do my work for me".
- [Problems cloning projects with cygwin's git](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38746110/734069)

  A reasonable question. One for which you received no downvotes.
- [Recursive to Iterative using a systematic method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38567618/734069)

  This is an exceptionally broad design question. It would probably work better on Prog.SE, but even there it would probably be too big and complex. You're basically asking how an entire field of study works. Your question probably doesn't deserve *twenty* downvotes, though.

So I would say that you're wrong about your question quality.

Comment: Thanks to take your time reviewing my stuff! That's really appreciated. One little note aside, when I say `they are not bad questions` that appreciation is made sticking to my own standards, not the SO's one. For instance, If I saw these type of "bad questions" from others and I would know how to answer them properly I'd definitely gave it a shot with a proactive attitude, I've done so many times in the short time contributing to SO. In any case, I'll try to adapt my criterion to strictly follow SO's rules to "improve" my questions and becoming less frustrated. +1

Comment: @BPL you may also want to scan META for guidance on answering overly broad (or other potentially off-topic) questions (which is "Get question in shape first, answer later or downvote and move on).

Comment: to be fair, most questions are "do my work for me" questions and often (if there is sufficient research before) this is not seen as really bad. otherwise we would have to delete approximately 90% of the questions on SO.

Comment: @Trilarion: There's a difference between "there's a bug in this code here" and "How do I do some complex task."