# Hot Meta Posts vote counter doesn't match question vote count

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, community-bulletin

Here's a bug I found where the hot meta posts vote counter for a question doesn't match the vote count. I don't think it's server lag because I don't *think* a question can receive 20 votes within a few minutes (although I don't quite know when the page is refreshed). Here's screenshots for proof:

[image: incorrect]

[image: correct]

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: The Codeless Code: [Monday, Monday](http://thecodelesscode.com/case/158) - the [rest of the topic](http://thecodelesscode.com/topics/caching) is a good read too.

Answer (score 13):

That little sidebar is shown almost *everywhere* on Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Overflow. As such it is way too expensive to get the latest and greatest vote totals for the posts that are included. That would require several database queries for the tens of thousands of times that little box is rendered.

So, instead, the numbers are cached. Once every so often ([every 20 minutes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252465/can-the-threshold-for-what-makes-it-into-the-community-bulletin-be-raised/252467#252467) to be precise) the box is re-built and the *then-current post score* is included.

In other words, this is not a bug, but [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

Comment: How often is the cache refreshed?

Comment: @Milo: Shog [confirms it is 20 minutes](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252465/can-the-threshold-for-what-makes-it-into-the-community-bulletin-be-raised/252467#252467).

Answer (score 4):

The votes counter on *Hot Meta Posts* is correct when the post first appeared on the feature. <s>I don't know exactly how often it changes, but anecdotally it looks to be around every half hour.</s> It has been confirmed that it updates every 20 minutes.

So, if the post appeared on *Hot Meta Posts* 15 minutes ago, it's not unlikely that a few upvotes have occurred in that time; hence the discrepancy.