# What are the limitations to see a question in the hot meta posts

Tags: discussion, community-bulletin

In the `Hot Meta Posts` section, based on what criteria/condition the questions are populating.

There should be some logic behind that to push the questions in this section, it may be most upvoted or most viewed or most answered questions in the recent hours.

Recently, I see a question with 3 upvotes and less than 100 viewed is also existing in this section, so it is not purely based on most `upvoted/viewed/answered`.

May I know what are those criterias/conditions behind this section?

[image: Hot Meta Posts 1]

[image: Hot Meta Posts 2]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [What criteria are used to select the links that appear in the community bulletin sidebar block?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130621/how-are-the-contents-of-the-community-bulletin-determined) on Meta Stack Exchange:

> - If there is a community moderator **election**, [a link to it appears in the bulletin](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111673/create-a-permanent-link-to-the-electionarea-during-electiontime/132331#132331).

> - **Events** can be created with a start date and time, an end date and time, a simple title, and a link to something somewhere on the network. Current or upcoming events are listed, with those starting or ending nearest to the current time shown first.

> - If there are fewer than 4 events, **blog posts** from either [the Stack Exchange blog](http://blog.stackexchange.com/) or [the site's blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/blog-overflow/) are added to the list. A maximum of two posts will be shown, and only those posted in the past three days.

> - If there are still fewer than 4 items listed, then **[featured](/questions/tagged/featured) meta posts** are shown (only those scoring 0 or above).

> - If there are still under 4 items, the rest of the space is filled with **[hot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11602/what-formula-should-be-used-to-determine-hot-questions) [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) questions** not marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), scoring at least 3 and posted within the past two weeks. These are picked semi-randomly. At least *one* of these will always be added to the list, even if it pushes the length over 4.

However, that's just for sites in general. For Meta Stack Overflow, [there's a little different rules for this.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252467/2607247) Here, all questions scoring 3 or more posted in the last 3 days are added to the pool of eligible questions. The list is refreshed [after an hour](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252465/can-the-threshold-for-what-makes-it-into-the-community-bulletin-be-raised/252467#comment177265_252467) to give us new "Hot" questions.