# User created a Duplicate of own question, then deleted previous one

Tags: discussion, flags, duplicate-questions

I was scrolling through the [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) questions today, when I came across [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36531302/5620297). I had seen a very similar question the previous day (that I had answered), and after checking it out and realizing it was by the same user, I wrote [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36531302/regex-to-build-and-compilation-errors#comment60666419_36531302):

> [You asked this yesterday...?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36517744/5620297)

Then, seconds after I post the comment, the previous question gets deleted, so I updated my comment:

> [You asked this yesterday...?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36517744/5620297) **Edit:** And so as soon as I post the comment you delete it.... **Seriously?!**

The user then responds with this:

> Sorry Druzion but nobody was answering me so I've post another question more precise. Thanks a lot for your yesterday's answers.

I tried to flag as duplicate, however since that question was deleted, I cannot.

How should I deal with this?

---

**Edit:** It seems the user un-deleted his old question, and so I could flag the new one as a duplicate

Comment: I wouldn't care about it. If this user deletes too much of their questions, they will get a question ban.

Comment: How come this is a "HOT META POST"?

Comment: @Omar [See this answer, it explains what makes a meta post "hot."](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296425/what-are-the-limitations-to-see-a-question-in-the-hot-meta-posts/296453#296453) This question very easily qualifies at the moment.

Comment: @Omar No other **Hot** post available for today. that's why

Comment: *"but nobody was answering me"* ... *"Thanks a lot for your yesterday's answers"* ... yes, makes sense :D.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

To answer your original question - if the user deletes their older, less detailed question then that's not a problem. We want good questions on the site and if they get it right second time then that's good. Ideally we'd prefer they edited the original question, but if it's been fairly heavily down-voted then even an heroic edit might not be enough to get them answers.

If they do it enough however, they will get a question ban as Gothdo [pointed out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320757/user-created-a-duplicate-of-own-question-then-deleted-previous-one#comment331938_320757).

To answer your edit - if the original question remains (or is undeleted) then vote/flag for that to be closed as a duplicate of the newer one.

If you spot that a user is repeatedly doing this then please flag one of their posts. Question repetition is one of the things we message users about.

Comment: It would be *very* helpful in these cases if those who *did* provide answers had a way to get that content back easily, since in many cases it can be applied to the new question.  It's **really** frustrating to spend some time on an answer and then have it completely erased, and to be faced with a (better version of) the *same* question the next day.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I totally agree with you. It seems extremely unfair that you cannot at least *see* **your own** answer after the question has been deleted. And it is definitely frustrating that you cannot add your answer to the new post, all that time ans hard work wasted. I would totally support the implementation of this feature.

Comment: @Druzion It [seems like](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2645/225437) [there](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/183344/225437) have been feature requests for that, and that they've been declined. :(