# How does a question make it to the Hot Meta Posts panel?

Tags: discussion, community-bulletin

Surely this must be a duplicate but I couldn't find it. I was just curious how a question is chosen to be displayed on the Hot Meta Posts side panel.

Is it the number of views? Votes? Comments? Edits? Answers? A minimum wage Stack Overflow employee swapping questions in and out?

Comment: The duplicate suggestions are right, but since I am asking a question slightly more specific than those more general answers I will include the relevant quote below.

Answer (score 3):

> For Meta Stack Overflow only, we'll now be featuring all hot meta
>   questions scoring 3 or more in the bulletin. And we'll exclude those
>   more than 3 days old, to keep it fresh. As before, the list will be
>   chosen randomly every 20 minutes or thereabouts from the pool of
>   eligible questions.

Source: [Shog9](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252467/3681880)