# After removing the featured tag, featured items aren't unfeatured (that or they come back from the otherworld)

Tags: bug, community-bulletin

The [burnination request for the [godaddy]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/331817/792066), is on the community bulletin, featured, as of 17:32 UTC. The problem is that undo removed the tag from the question as 14:12:33Z, basically 3 hours and at least 1 forced cache refresh. Now, I'm aware that the list is cached, and there have been two cases where [users reported](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/32248762#32248762) that it isn't featured (which after refresh gets featured again), so there's something funky going on.

What I know is the following:

- Community bulletin is [cached for 1 hour](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236687/per-site-hot-meta-questions-are-still-hot-after-being-deleted?noredirect=1#comment827710_236687)
- It gets [refreshed every 20 minutes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252467/792066), and invalidated [if there's a event](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236687/per-site-hot-meta-questions-are-still-hot-after-being-deleted?noredirect=1#comment827714_236687) (new hot question, featured, etc.)
- [What criteria are used to select the links that appear in the community bulletin sidebar block?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/130621/213575)

Comment: I think there was a period roughly 30 minutes after the post was un-featured that it was off the community board, but now it's back.

Comment: The post isn't in the featured list anymore.

Comment: ... And it's back on the featured list!

Comment: @Tunaki HAHAHHAHAHAHA...

Comment: I haven't seen it since the featured tag was removed, and I was browsing yesterday almost the whole day (It's 09:25 for me right now) :p

Comment: Yup, it's happening again. Featured tag removed 5 hours ago, question still appears in the bulletin.