# Are British/International English terms acceptable? (e.g. 'brackets' instead of 'parentheses')

Tags: discussion, english

I had someone edit a post of mine to 'correct' my naming of the symbols `()` from "brackets" to "parentheses".

In British English "brackets" is the usual term.  This got me wondering: **Is US-English the only accepted variant for this site?**

There are arguments in both directions - on the one hoof **standardization is good**, but on the other hoof **differing terms for things will be encountered in the real world, so it may be counterproductive to pretend they do not exist.**

*What's the consensus for this site?*

Comment: As a Dutchman with a reasonable grasp of English (living in the UK at the moment, married to a Scot), I wasn't aware that British English called those *brackets*. I always use the term 'parenthesis', reserving brackets for `[]`, or *square* brackets.

Comment: We call them:  ()=brackets; []=square brackets; {}=braces; <>=angle brackets

Comment: And, no, US-English is not the only accepted variant. I try to use British spelling where possible, my wife will happily point out when I use US spelling or expression whenever the opportunity arises.

Comment: And the Oxford English dictionary calls *all* of those [brackets](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bracket), as a group.

Comment: But I learned something today, *parenthesis* as a name for the round brackets is indeed [American English](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/parenthesis); in proper English [the term exists but doesn't refer to the brackets](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/parenthesis).

Comment: Yep they are all *kinds* of brackets, but if the type is not specified explicitly then just saying "brackets" on its own defaults to meaning parentheses.

Comment: Yes the kind of textual afterthought put in brackets is referred to as a parenthetical.

Comment: I'm going to the USA next week to visit a friend, and we will be building things out of aluminium - I'm sure we will have that discussion more than a few times :P

Comment: Interestingly US English is actually closer to old English than current British English.

Comment: I use them interchangeably, like when stating my favourite color is grey. Keeps people on their toes.

Comment: @Amicable: but English English is closer to English than American English.  Thank goodness we don't have to use Shakespearian or Chaucerian or Beowulfian English on SO!

Comment: American (Programmer) English: `() = "parentheses"; [] = "square brackets"; {} = "curly braces"; <> = "angle brackets"` `:P`

Comment: Oh, one more, in American (Programmer) English, I've also seen heard `{}` referred to as "curly brackets". So you see, they're all so many different kinds of ***brackets!*** `:P`

Comment: I'm British. I think context is important here. What might be referred to as a bracket in idiomatic English, is more normally referred to as a parenthesis in a computer science context. So if the appropriate character set specification (ascii, iso 8859, etc) defines thsa bit pattern as a "left parenthesis) then left parenthesis it is, thus trumping the OED. Editing the question was going too far, but I see it as an issue of domain specific English v. idiomatic English, rather that a transatlantic one.

Comment: Related (to the comments, not particularly much to the question): http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3379/bracket-vs-brace, http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/302/what-is-the-most-professional-name-for-squiggly-bracket, http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14252/what-is-the-common-name-for-brackets-braces-and-parentheses

Comment: This has (annoyingly) happened to me on a couple of occasions, too.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That use of [*parenthesis*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/parenthesis) comes from latin which took it from ancient greek *parentithemi* (to put between or to embed). In Italian we use the term *parentesi* for *all* the symbols `()`, `[]`, `{}` and `<>` specifying the shape (e.g. *parentesi tonde* for `()` which would be translated *round brackets* in English). No idea why *round brackets* doesn't seem be actually used in English (at least it was never mentioned in the comments).

Comment: @Bakuriu It's because they are the "normal" brackets. So you might say "curly brackets or round brackets?" if you were trying to differentiate between the two, but if you were just talking about `()` and didn't need to distinguish from another kind of bracket you'd just say "brackets".

Comment: Out of all the things we could debate about on Meta, we debate about the names of these 8 little symbols `() [] {} <> <sigh> :P` Another [bike-shed issue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parkinson's_law_of_triviality).

Comment: @Cupcake: and of all the things I could be doing with my time, I choose to spend some on meta.stackoverflow. The place is a giant bikeshed, but as long as people are doing it because they want to spend time on bikesheds that's fine ;-)

Comment: It's a silly edit, but the convention follows partly because of this American. http://www.bobbemer.com/BRACES.HTM

Comment: @SteveJessop I'm only here [because The Powers That Be won't let me leave](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251920/456814) `:P`

Comment: In my experience (US) we call them: **()=parentheses; []=braces or square braces; {}=curly braces; <>=brackets or angle brackets**

Comment: Is "on the one hoof... on the other hoof" British English usage? :-) I was going to edit the question to "on the one hand..." but I thought that would have been to subtle a joke. :-)

Comment: @StuartMarks It probably has more to do with the poster being a zebra than being a Brit.

Comment: @StuartMarks see my profile/picture for the answer to that...  (edit: sniped!)

Comment: They are called brackets because they are used to bracket things.

Comment: I once saw an editorial review of a journal paper where the author incurred the reviewer's wrath over the word "whilst". The author was from England and the (anonymous) reviewer was from who knows where (probably a compatriot of mine from the good ol' USA). The reviewer's comment was something to the effect that the author needed to learn correct English or at least have a native English speaker review the author's work before submission. Sadly, even if we all agree that British English is acceptable on SO, that isn't going to stop ignorant editors from "fixing" your posts.

Comment: Of course it's acceptable, whoever changed it needs a slap. Hope this helps.

Comment: @JoeHarper: Indeed.  However, such arguments readily fall down when we Brits pronounce "Leicester" without the "ice".

Comment: Over my way it's: ()=brackets; []=square brackets; {}=curly brackets; <>=angle brackets

Comment: INTERCAL names are unambiguous! `()` = wax/wane, `[]` = U turn/U turn back, `{}` = embrace/bracelet, `<>` = angle/right angle. Bonus: `&` = ampersand.

Comment: In my opinion both are fine but i agree with @MartijnPieters , as a dutch student my interpretation for the word "brackets" refers to the group of all different brackets. If you refer to brackets i assume you refer to square brackets while saying parenthesis i assume you mean  "()". I think this is because square-brackets; curly-brackets; angle-brackets all have a prefix while just "brackets" doesn't. Making it unclear which brackets you meant, leaving it open for interpretation. So perhaps "round brackets" will be more clear but sounds a bit off in my opinion. So i would go for parenthesis.

Comment: I've always read "brackets" to refer to "square brackets" so that's an unfortunate difference between the two varieties...

Comment: @pinoyyid ascii is American. It is even in the name. Thus is is not unreasonable it would use an American word to describe brackets... iso 8859 and UTF8 were then also explicitly backwards compatible with ascii so also based around American English, therefore I do not think any of these are good examples of a non regional usage.

Comment: @MrZebra, interestingly Sir Humphry Davy, the very British chemist who first identified it, referred to it as *alumium* or *aluminum*, but never *aluminium*.

Comment: Is it not simple a case that the word *parenthesis* refers to a *"a word or phrase inserted as an explanation or afterthought into a passage which is grammatically complete without it"* and it just so happens that usually it is surrounded by *brackets* but can be other characters. So `()` are brackets, `[]` are brackets and `{}` are brackets they are all **brackets**, the fact they are used in *parenthesis* doesn't change what they are.

Comment: Well, since English originated in England, I'd say "Yes" it's acceptable.

Comment: In addition to the above:  In the US, I refer to `{}` as _squiggly brackets_.  I know it's not a proper term, but at the same time, no one mistakes which one it is.

Comment: @Izkata squiggly brackets is also used in the UK. As you indeed say, no one can mistake what it means

Comment: I've always called **`()`** parentheses, **`[]`** brackets, and
**`{}`** curly brackets.

Comment: As a Canadian I would also call these () brackets. I've always though parentheses was just a fancy word for brackets.

Comment: @Jodrell — You may be saddened to learn that North America is not a british colony anymore.

Comment: When I was in Scotland, and I naturally said *parentheses*, it made my colleagues smile, I had used a savant word. :-)

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco my feelings are mixed :-p Likewise, there is good and bad here in the First World. However, I am delighted that my first language, however mutated, seems to be the "Lingua Franca" for software engineering (pun intended.)

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco, I can't decide if I should thank the British Empire or Hollywood, I suspect praise should be divided.

Comment: In Australia we also call them as in the UK: ()=brackets; []=square brackets; {}=braces or curly brackets; <>=angle brackets. To call them "parentheses" seems a bit pretentious.

Comment: How is it going to be with `color` and `colour`? :P

Comment: Round brackets, anyone?

Comment: **Of cause it's acceptable.** I'm British (not English) and I'm certainly NOT going to be changing a question to American English just to satisfy a small group of users.

Comment: @cybermonkey you actually (probably) satisfy a smaller group of users by keeping it in British English

Comment: @royhowie Well, everyone who can speak English are able to read both American English and British English, so why bother going through the pain to satisfy such a small minority of users?

Comment: As a C++98 programmer, I call `()` "method call", `[]` "array subscript", `{}` "block" and `<>` "oh, that missing space again...."

Comment: In school (India) we were taught "brackets": small brackets for `()`, square brackets for `[]`, and curly brackets for `{}`. When I moved to job I used small brackets, colleagues (India) didn't get it, I cut it down to brackets, then again all in vain, and ultimately, I'd to move to parenthesis for `()`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Actually, the link you posted to OED _does_ use the plural form (parentheses) to [refer to the 'brackets' themselves](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/parenthesis). It's definition 1.1.

Comment: @royhowie The statement about satisfying a smaller group of users by keeping it in British English is only true when people from neither the US nor the UK have a neutral stance toward either of those English varieties, but that is rarely the case, as I will now demonstrate: US English is the abomination of the two! A lot of people will show a certain amount of sympathy for one of the two and will thus be biased instead of neutral.

Comment: @user456814 - I want a keyboard that lets me use shelf brackets. :-P

Answer (score 188, accepted):

Yes, British (aka "Proper") English is acceptable.

Edits to change things to American English should be rejected or rolled back - unless they are part of wider edits to make improvements to the post. In that case it's probably not worth getting worked up over it.

If there is any doubt over the terminology then changing it is acceptable, but in this case "brackets" should be understandable to everyone, though it would probably be better to use the more precise term for the *type* of brackets being referred to.

Things like using "doubt" for "question" *should* be changed as that usage is idiomatic to one region and can (and indeed has) caused confusion.

Comment: What about other dialects like e.g. idioms common in India like "do the needful" and "doubt" instead of question?

Comment: @MadScientist - "do the needful" needs to be burnt with fire. "doubt" should really be replaced by "question".

Comment: However, it should be noted that American English is to be used for tags.

Comment: Hmmm. "Do the needful" is Indian English, in the same way that using "brackets" to refer to what I call parentheses is British English. I'm not a fan of it either, but.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta - to me it implies an order or imperative request. i.e. *telling* the reader to do something.

Comment: @George Stocker: I see what you did there.

Comment: @ChrisF "in this case 'brackets' should be understandable to everyone." See [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252503/is-british-international-english-acceptable#comment8884_252503). If someone writes "brackets", I'm going to think `[]` or `<>`. Maybe be more specific to avoid confusion anyways (ha! ["anyways" is American English!](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/anyways?q=anyways) Darn Yankees! `:P`), like "round brackets"...ewww `:P`

Comment: See also [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252503/is-british-international-english-acceptable/252504#comment8908_252503).

Comment: I had one on Pets.SE where "vet" got changed to "veterinarian". This is a US word; to be correctly lengthened in British English you'd have to say "veterinary surgeon", not "veterinarian". Sometimes people just don't realise they're correcting you, especially if they are an American English speaker; we get much more exposed to their dialect than they to ours.

Comment: @ChrisF: You seem to be saying that British English is not idiomatic to one region. I'm British, but I must admit there's a lot less pink on the map than there used to be. For most differences between British English and US English, I would hesitate to assert confidently that Australia, NZ, Canada,  India follow the British version. If they don't then then the Proper version is starting to look idiomatic to one region. So how should I determine which British English terms are regional?

Comment: "unless they are part of wider edits to make improvements to the post."
I would argue that specifying the type of brackets is making the post clearer to everyone who does not speak the dialect of British English. "Parenthesis" is very clear, but "brackets" has a different meaning in each dialect.

Comment: Except Wikipedia says brackets are these `[]` and parentheses are these `()` (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket) and most programming languages call these `[]` brackets and these parentheses `()`, like it or not (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_programming_languages_by_type#Curly-bracket_languages). So to call it anything else isn't picking on a person, just wrong.

Comment: @ChrisF: Spoken like a true brit. ;)

Comment: @staticx - the question mentioned brackets but was about the wider acceptability of non-American spellings and usages.

Comment: @SteveJessop - All variants of English are acceptable. It's just that some variants are less clear than others.

Comment: (As long as its not Eye-rak for Iraq or Moss-cow-that-moos for Moscow) 
I think context is important. I speak English English, as opposed to US English. From primary school mathematics, sciences and literature all the way to university level, these "()" have always been brackets... Except in programming. 

A great deal of language influence in programming is US English, so I am conditioned to use it when appropriate. But only in reference to code. Otherwise it's colour, queue, cheque, programme...etc

Comment: I don't consider "Indian English" to be a valid version of **Native** English, as it is a 2nd language to it's users.

Comment: @staticx Wikipedia is not a definitive source. It's whatever whoever edited it last put. Brackets are brackets in British English and I've been programming professionally in England for nearly 20 years without ever once using the term "parenthesis" or having anyone else use the term to me.

Comment: @Tim: understood, but it is colloquially known as brackets and parentheses in programming circles

Comment: @staticx In your local programming circles it is. However that is not true for all programming circles everywhere, hence the discussion.

Comment: @Tim: Norwegians I know use the so called American way. The American term is more prevalent than the British way.

Comment: @staticx I'm not disputing that as I have no evidence either way and it is irrelevant anyway. What I am disputing is 1. using wikipedia as a definitive source and 2. that a way is "wrong" just because it may not be the way you do it.

Comment: @Tim: I am not saying it is wrong. But if we must chose a convention, then I suggest we chose the one thats more popular. Wikipedia is just fine. I don't think an edit like that alone is substantial enough thouggh. More needs to be changed in the question.

Comment: @staticx This is turning into a discussion-in-comments so I'm dropping out - however go read your original post where you cited Wikipedia and ended with "just wrong". Happy to hear you've changed your mind.:)

Comment: @Tim: I retract the just wrong..too strong of a statement. Have a good day

Comment: Interestingly enough, "do the needful" was "current in both British and American English well into the early 20th century" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do_the_needful).

Comment: @user919426 Last I checked, "queue" is still spelled "queue" in American English.

Comment: @user919426 Which is funny, because a few months ago, I was told by a London native (sitting next to me in the office) that they are parentheses all the time...

Comment: British English, aka Proper English, aka English...

Comment: @JAB, while the spelling doesn't differ on queue, BrE uses the word in a sense not common in AmE: a line of people, such as one to place an order at a fast food restaurant. BrE also uses queue as a verb (equivalent to AmE "get in line"), and while one might use queue in AmE as a verb, it is almost guaranteed to be computing-related (ie, a queue structure).

Comment: -1 for implying American English is improper? I once said "elevator" to a businessman and wasn't glared at.

Comment: I disagree brackets is not clear that you mean parenthesis ... this is not the same as something like colour vs color

Comment: @IanRingrose Judging by your use of "it's", I suppose English is your 2nd language as well? ;)

Comment: @IanRingrose I worked with an Indian fellow for some years (we were both foreigners in the US) and his, his family's, and apparently a _great_ many Indians', first language was English. Hindi was, to him, purely like Latin to a pre-Vatican II Roman Catholic.

Comment: @Ben "British English" proper???? My parents are Geordie, I was born in London, and raised in Cumberland. Which of those mutually incomprehensible dialects was proper?

Comment: I was quoting Chris @auspex,

Comment: Thanks, being able to edit my post to use "amortised" makes me feel 1000 times better; I really dislike it when people edit my posts and use US-only spellings: http://stackoverflow.com/a/196022/13 :-D

Comment: I do not know how anyone can agree with the claim that 'in this case "brackets" should be understandable to everyone'.  See [Alex's answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252671/103167)  Looked through the whole C# spec and C++ Standard and found *brackets* used to refer to `[]` and `<>` but never `()`.

Comment: Once I had my post edited and "colour" replaced by "color" with a comment "fixing typing errors". I believe this is ridiculous.

Comment: You have something against [Oxford Spelling](http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/4896/898), @ChrisJester-Young?

Comment: @TRiG Yes, I'm a New Zealander, and in New Zealand, -ise is strongly preferred.

Comment: I don't know about prior discussion here, but Indian English is common on Math.SE, and it is considered rude there to change it. It doesn't take very long to figure out that "doubt" is a term for a sort of question. Since there are many millions of English speakers in India, I think they have at least as much a right to their variations as the folks from elsewhere.

Comment: If "brackets" is ambiguous in context, the correct way to fix it is to qualify it: "round brackets".

Comment: Bear in mind that I have done good edits with the British 'colour' (I'm British but not English), which have been rejected because they used the 'wrong spelling'

Comment: What a non-sense answer. I'm having a fight with users because a post is half fixed with some British stuff and when I fix the rest to obviously American English I'm getting called out because I changed back the only word they bothered to fix. How on earth is this going to work for non-native speakers, It is difficult enough, you know.

Answer (score 137):

Even though I'm British, I use "parentheses" because (like it or not) American English is dominant in programming. But, just as importantly, "brackets" is also the generic term for (i.e. the hypernym of) parentheses, square brackets, curly brackets and angle brackets. Whereas parentheses is unambiguous.

Changing colour to color, or grey to gray, might be harder to justify, though. (Except in a question about CSS colour names...).

Comment: I'm usually reluctant to use American English terms and spellings, but "parenthesis" is one term I do use because I've had "brackets" edited more than once on Stack Overflow.  I'm so used to it now that I use "parenthesis" everywhere.

Comment: I find myself doing the same, for clarity - British people generally understand it (especially programmers, because they've seen American documentation and specs for their languages), and it removes any ambiguity for what kind of brackets you meant. Write for your audience... but editing a post just to change that seems silly unless it really does cause ambiguity.

Comment: +1, this is what I think. I'm British and I might say "brackets" when talking about written English but for code I always say "parentheses" precisely to avoid the question "which kind of brackets?". (Also, in my style of writing I make a lot of parenthetical asides (but I'd never call them bracketed asides))

Comment: In spoken language everywhere, there aren't these hard distinctions, but when I learned to program at home, dictating code to another from a magazine, it becomes very important to clearly say "x equals f bracket two close bracket".  Likewise in writing about code it's sometimes clearer to spell out the punctuation, rather than embed the punctuation in the sentence -- which could confuse the reader as to the intent.

Comment: +1 For parentheses being unambiguos. Brittish english should not be considered wrong in any way, but in this specific case *parentheses* should be preferred over *brackets* just because it's a bit clearer.

Comment: But brackets is unambiguous in British English, because () = brackets, [] = square brackets and {} = curly brackets. IME parentheses is rarely used in Britain.

Comment: @justinhj Exactly. Until I got into programming I had never heard anyone say parentheses before in normal conversation. Even when studying English it was always described as brackets when talking about punctuation.

Comment: Both `gray` *and* `grey` are valid CSS, though.

Comment: @justinhj: Not everyone speaks British English.  And "parentheses" is unambiguous in every common dialect.

Comment: In programming context, undebatable unambiguous is better than good style. Parentheses and round brackets (), square brackets [], curly brackets {} cannot be misunderstood.

Comment: I prefer 'paren'. Absolutely unambiguous, and bound to irritate almost everybody.

Comment: Quite a lot of Americans call their language "American" and this is perfectly reasonable: "English" literally means "language of the people of England". "US English" is an oxymoron as is "Canadian French". If you declare that the language to be used is "English" then British spellings ought to be used. Since the preponderance of literature in software development uses American, the only sensible course is to acknowledge that it is mislabelled as being in English, try not to make the mess any worse, and for new works use correct labelling and spelling consistent with the standard in use.

Comment: I use a mix of both American and British English. Sometimes I type "Colour", but usually "Color". I never write "gray", only "grey". And I do other mix and matching between the two dialects. What does this make me?

Answer (score 51):

In a similar vein to [Prime624's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252638/456814) it would be appropriate to use the appropriate spelling in the context of the programming language, so if the language spec refers to parentheses.

For example the [ECMA-334 C# Language Specification.](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdf) refers to `()` as parenthesis:

> 14.5.3 Parenthesized expressions
>   A parenthesized-expression consists of an expression enclosed in parentheses.  parenthesized-expression: 
>   ( expression )
>
> A parenthesized-expression is evaluated by evaluating the expression
>   within the parentheses. If the expression within the parentheses
>   denotes a namespace or type, a compile-time error occurs.

And the CSS specification says colours are defined by `color`.

If however the meaning of the question is clearly understandable by any reader of English, then I don't think it is required to be changed. However if the spelling of the word e.g. colour / color is important syntactically, then it should be changed.

Answer (score 29):

There is a practical reason to discourage linguistic diversity: **it breaks searching**. So I'd recommend to use more conventional words when possible when writing on technical subjects. I myself have a habit to write "colour" instead of "color", "dialogue" instead of "dialog" etc. because this is how I was taught at school but I do my best avoiding this here just because of the reason I've mentioned.

Also, as Darren Cook has mentioned, "brackets" is an **ambiguous** generic term that can mean (), [], {} or whatever while "parentheses" is a standard term for round brackets used conventionally not only by programmers but also by scientists all over the world.

At the same time there are words for which I don't know what the common convention is. For example I use (again, because this is how I was taught all the way) "formulae" for the plural of "formula" and "indices" for the plural of "index" but I suspect many people can be using other forms and I don't know how many.

Comment: Except Wikipedia says brackets are these `[]` and parentheses are these `()` (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket) and most programming languages call these `[]` brackets and these parentheses `()`, like it or not (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_programming_languages_by_type#Curly-bracket_languages). So to call it anything else isn't picking on a person, just wrong.

Comment: Since when has Wikipedia became an authoritative source of definitions, @staticx? http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bracket?q=Brackets says "Each of a pair of marks ( ) [ ] { } 〈 〉 used to enclose words or figures so as to separate them from the context"

Comment: It's the closest canonical source I find at the moment. This guy pretty much called them braces (`{`) from the beginning. (http://www.bobbemer.com/BRACES.HTM). Within Algol 60 and 68 (C was written in 1972 and BCPL in 1966), the square bracket was used to designate an index into an array or matrix. I don't think you can rely on oxford dictionaries as a canonical source for programming language syntax definitions.

Comment: And it actually seems Bob Bemer added 11 characters which he calls square brackets and braces. So he is probably the primary source if there can't be any others found for the proper convention. "The above proves that I was the source responsible for placing 11 different characters into ASCII (point 1), and for at least 8 of these (with the possible exception of the vertical bar, and the square brackets of the LGP-30) it was the first placement in the internal character set of any computer (point 2)."

Comment: Practically I'd discourage use of the bare "brackets" word at all as it in fact is (for some people at least) ambiguous unless obvious from the context. Simply use "parentheses" (or "round brackets" if you insist) for (), "square brackets" for [], and "curly braces/brackets" for {}.

Comment: I agree. Less ambiguous. I was just pointing out that the American influence was strong in a lot of these terms that we take for granted. It's not meaning to be hegemonic. One just has to look at history and how American's had a big influence on a lot of the originating standards and still have a big influence. This is not to put down any other culture, just stating a fact.

Comment: In my oppinion editing a question to replace "brackets" with a more unambiguous word meaning the particular kind definitely is a good idea. If one insists writing British, "parenthesis" is not an americanism - in fact it is included in the Oxford UK English dictionary too.

Comment: I think that if that's the only edit, then no..it isn't substantial enough to merit an edit. But could be lumped in with other edits

Comment: Actually I'd say the opposite, it HELPS searching.  Suppose I have never heard the word "parentheses", and I type "brackets" into the search.  If ALL I get back is [] then that is of no help.  However if I get back results with () then I will be able to see from other answers and comments that other people call them parentheses, and I will now be aware that there is another name for them.

Comment: Ivan, You are correct that Wikipedia should not be cited as the authoritative source for any topic, but the bibliography of a Wikipedia article is _supposed_  to provide those links. For example, [This Link](http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/parens.asp) was reference #6 in the article mentioned by @staticx

Comment: "football" is an ambiguous generic term that can mean "american football" or "soccer".  Better to use the term "soccer" (e.g., FISA instead of FIFA).

Comment: Exactly, @user2023861, this is why I never write just "football" and always write "american football" or "football (soccer)" (or just "soccer") instead (even though I am not american and football clearly means the actual football (the game played by feet with a ball, not by hands with an egg) for me).

Comment: It does not break searching. Search engines know very well about synonyms.

Comment: @user2023861  So when the americans change the meaning of something, the original definition becomes 'ambiguous'?

Comment: While not specific to Americans, yes, the original definition becomes ambiguous. Especially on a popular website. I was using an analogy to make a point. If we were removing ambiguity, we would be using "parentheses" and "soccer".

Comment: @user2023861: I disagree about football; just because the USA decides to invent a game and give it a name that has been given to another game already, doesn't mean that the rest of the world should start naming that other game something else to avoid confusion for those poor Muricans. No, let them wallow in their mistake, the rest of the world can just carry on living.

Answer (score 9):

As a matter of fact, it is not a matter of language. It's matter of 2 rep points for editing. There are characters, who earn thousands of reputation points adding occasional commas and spaces to already closed (and eventually soon to be deleted) questions.

This edit was apparently of this kind.

Comment: cf. the Oxford comma

Comment: Improving punctuation and grammar can make a question easier to understand some times. I don't do this myself usually but am grateful to those doing it for me.

Comment: I did not even know you earn rep by editing. This new knowledge now puts me in a non-voluntary position, argh; instead of social philanthropist I now feel like an asocial and egoistic misanthropist.

Comment: @phresnel You only get rep for *suggesting* edits that are subsequently approved. Once you've earned the [edit privilege](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) at 2000 rep, you get nothing except a sense of satisfaction at having improved the world around you :)

Comment: Yay, I love humans :D

Answer (score 7):

American, British, and International English should all be acceptable on a globally-targeted, community-based website without a second glance.

Different English dialects tend to be **very** similar and **very** cross-understandable.  Other languages are not like this, but English is.  There are **rare** occasions where issues may arise, such as with the word "doubt", as ChrisF mentioned.  I can think of a couple of different words like this.  By and large though, this is only a small drop in the bucket, compared to the same kind of confusion that will be caused by different indivduals' vocabulary **within the same dialect**.

Furthermore there are three basic versions of English that are understood globally - American, British, and International.  That's not to say each one is official globally (English itself is not generally used in many countries).  That's not to say that at least two versions don't each have different sub-dialects.  But it is to say that anyone, throughout the world, who uses English regularly will generally have been somewhat exposed to all three.  This site is international, larging consisting of members from countries that don't speak English at all, so trying to impose one particular dialect really goes against the rhyme and reason of the community.

Lastly any gains will be tiny and meaningless.  This is somewhat due to the second paragraph.  But think about it: would you rather invest weeks, even months, working on bug fixes for the site, or would you rather spend it dividing the community against itself to save someone from having to look up two measly words in a dictionary?  You'll have people adamantly standing on both sides of the fence for months, gradually tearing the community apart - and when this community is completely international, how would you ever justify one side over the other?

Going back to the word "doubt", I remember being initially confused by this a few years ago, when I started working for an Indian company, but I could still tell what they were talking about, even before catching up to speed.  There are simply bigger fish to fry.

Answer (score 6):

I think that generally, any dictionary-recognized English should be acceptable. However, in the case of specific programming terms, I think that American (programmer) English should be required. In the same way that using "colour" is not acceptable in programming, and "color" is the correct way. When speaking generally, "colour" vs "color" shouldn't matter, but when specifically coding it, it should.

[To quote @Cupcake](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252503/is-british-international-english-acceptable?answertab=oldest#comment8884_252503):

> American (Programmer) English: `() = "parentheses"; [] = "square brackets"; {} = "curly braces"; <> = "angle brackets"`

Comment: Clarification: what do you mean by "American (programmer) English"? Does "programmer" add an extra qualification to "American English", or are the brackets intended to convey an identity between "American English" and "programmer English"?

Comment: They are generally equivalent, as computers and programming were created in America.

Comment: @Prime624 I find that a vaguely offensive and USA-centric view, for example Alan Turing was british...

Comment: @MichaelAnderson I mean no offense. I completely acknowledge the contributions of non-American people to technology. I was just trying to explain the reason why words in programming languages generally use American English. It's a shame that computers can't understand multiple languages, but it's a fact, and as programmers, we must work with it. If computers were invented in France, we would all probably be programming in French. Again, no offense intended.

Comment: To be clear, it wasn't the answer that I found agravating - as that is purely an expression of opinion - it was the "... as computers and programming were created in America." claim in the following comment.

Comment: I did some research and I found I was wrong. Sorry for that assumption.

Comment: @Prime624: No probs. Babbage was English, Boole was English but lived in Ireland, Jacquard was French, Lovelace was English, Turing was English, von Neumann was Hungarian, Berners-Lee is English... and tons more Europeans in the list of [prominent people in the history of programming languages]( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_programming_languages#Prominent_people) not forgetting the Soviets too.

Comment: @duplode 6 hours later, I'm not sure why I specified "American (Programmer) English" in brackets/parentheses/round-brackets/whatever `:P` I don't know, maybe I just wanted it to sound **extra nerdy?** `0_0 :P`

Comment: I use `colour` as a variable name in programming all the time, seems acceptable to me `;)`.

Comment: I think you need to look up who actually made popular programming languages before making a broad statement that programming was created in America.

Comment: To me brackets are `()` unless defined otherwise. It's not only americans who program

Comment: Actually, there was a library a while ago that I used often that forced you to use colour when accessing a method.  I forget the name.  Annoying as anything, but it usually made me smile at the same time.

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen: Anyone who has studied computer languages, know they weren't all made in America (tm), but rather a collaborative worldwide effort. That being said, Bell Labs had a big influence circa 1970s. ALGOL was a big influence (https://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/188455/why-do-programming-languages-especially-c-use-curly-braces-and-not-square-ones)

Comment: @ajtrichards_wales: It's not a slight, but rather a fact. This American pretty much set the standard. Read up about Bob Bemer. http://www.bobbemer.com/BRACES.HTM

Comment: As a programmer who doesn't speak American, I object to the identification of "American English" with "programmer English".  There are whole communities of programmers who refer to `()` as "brackets", and still believe themselves to be speaking English when they do so.

Comment: I would like to +1 on @DavidWallace statement and add one more. I find it positively _offensive_ that “Americans” think they “own” things like – in this case – the domain of a computer programmer and their way to express things.

Comment: Using "colour" is perfectly acceptable in programming.  In fact, wxPython (a very popular python library) chose "colour" instead of "color" (http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Colour-class.html).  @demongolem - maybe this is the library you were thinking of.  As a Canadian, I actually prefer this spelling.

Comment: @Gerrat Exactly!  I was thinking of wxPython.

Comment: @mirabilos: Americans don't think they own programming. It's just the terms that people are used to come a lot from American-style English. It's not like a bunch of American programmers are trying to install a sort of hegemony

Comment: @staticx - that's a very interesting comment. I assert that the hegemony you mention is quite real (good choice of words, too). It was certainly an accident of circumstance, but you need only look at these comments to see that because they find it convenient, Americans *do* protect the status quo.

Comment: @Peter: if it isn't broke, don't fix it.

Comment: @staticx - Quite. From a British perspective, American spelling *is* broken. Most of the differences came from one angry man with a barrow to push and a printing press: Noah Webster did *not* like the British. Please note that I am merely noting points of interest, and not advocating any particular course of action.

Comment: @Peter: Of course. It really doesnt matter to me. I am just pointing out that the convention is the convention and it has been that way in many programming circles for a long time. I don't see it changing. I mentioned somewhere else that merely changing it from brackets to parentheses in the post isn't substantial enough to warrant an edit. But if coupled with another edit would be fine. But both can live together in harmony as long as it is understood.

Answer (score 6):

There is one example that, in my opinion, makes British English completely acceptable: [the difference in quotation punctuation](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/punctuation-errors-american-and-british-quotation-marks/).  I can't stand putting punctuation inside of the quotations, probably due to the use of quotation marks denoting `string literals` in most programming languages.  The current sentence's punctuation has nothing to do with the quote.

Comment: Absolutely. I sometimes prefer to refer to this as "Programming Quotation" to lift its belonging above English dialects. In German, we have confusing rules, too. I never found that logical.

Comment: In proper American English, the same rules apply in the example that's supposed to demonstrate British English.  In that case, all they had was a period at the end of the quote, and in American English, there are many cases in which it would go after the quotation marks, not inside them.  Here's an example of the distinction in American English:  Sentence 1: Then he said, "No, sir, I did not witness that horrible incident."  Sentence 2: When interviewed, Mr. Smith referred to the train wreck as a "horrible incident".

Comment: That being said, the article seems to suggest British English always follows the style of Sentence 2.

Answer (score 3):

I think that [Basic English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_English) should be the acceptable core. As there are many SO participants who don't use English as their native language. It should be made possible for them to access the SO site both by asking questions and by writing answers.

Requirement for flowery or university-style British or American English is hard to follow (e.g. for me).

I'd be glad if some native speaker would fix my grammar. Aside from that - technical terms should be spelled the way they appear in technical literature, e.g. in MSDN library

Comment: I get a chuckle when you call the MSDN library "technical literature", but that's just because I have this thing about Microsoft.

Answer (score 2):

I would say as long as people understand what you mean when asking the question, it shouldn't matter at all what you use. As long as the English isn't horribly broken or grammatically demonic, there shouldn't be any need to change it from brackets. It might not be the "correct" term, but it's what I personally would search anyway.

In regards to the search issues, alternate spellings of the same words (colour - color, grey-gray) are usually freely interchangeable. Alternate names for the same words isn't really relevant, since people have so many ways of describing the same issue, sometimes using completely different words, regardless of American or English English

Comment: It's probably worth noting that there are an unfortunate number of things in programming that are culturally specific.  I use commas to separate groups of three digits, but some countries use periods, which greatly offends my sensibilities of using a period as a decimal point.

Comment: The decimal points. Oh the decimal points

Comment: It's a decimal separator, not a decimal point. And remember it's not left and right brackets, but opening and closing brackets, so your text doesn't get messed up when you use a right-to-left writing system.

Comment: I think that this here is probably the root of the problem. You've corrected my terminology to be the more specific/official terms, but the meaning of my sentence hasn't changed. Decimal point is unmistakably a decimal separator, which mirrors most of the British/International English issues

Comment: Ellimist0 - I'm fairly sure that @gnasher729 is taking the mickey.

Answer (score 2):

The usage on Wikipedia has come up in a few comments above. Wikipedia has an applicable style guideline: [Retaining the existing variety](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:RETAIN#Retaining_the_existing_variety).

> When an English variety's consistent usage has been established in an article, it is maintained in the absence of consensus to the contrary. With few exceptions (e.g. when a topic has strong national ties or a term/spelling carries less ambiguity), there is no valid reason for such a change.
>
> When no English variety has been established and discussion cannot resolve the issue, the variety used in the first non-stub revision is considered the default. If no English variety was used consistently, the tie is broken by the first post-stub contributor to introduce text written in a particular English variety. The variety established for use in a given article can be documented by placing the appropriate Varieties of English template on its talk page.
>
> An article should not be edited or renamed simply to switch from one valid use of English to another. The {{subst:uw-lang}} template may be placed on an editor's talk page to explain this to him or her.

To adapt this policy to SO, I feel that edits to a question or answer should preserve the original author's choice of variety. There is no need for the answers to be consistent with the question unless it results in an ambiguous or misleading answer - if, say, some piece of terminology used in the question has different meanings in different varieties of English, and the answer is wrong because of the misunderstanding. Of course, if that happens, the answer should just be voted down, not edited.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps we ought to have language/idiom modes (of which GB-English and US-English would be two) on the same basis as spelling dictionaries. Without that, I prefer a standard, even if, as it would be US English, it isn't my dialect.

Comment: Maybe like a cool pirate translater Aye Mate let me regale you a tale of the HMS Brackets.

Answer (score -3):

*** edit fixed my grammar thanks ***

Brackets in English is any delimiter and for all intents and purposes it's slang.

Be individuals but not lazy programers use universal coding language and be specific if you have to name a character.

*** edit add some flair ***
According to ECMAScript in the book of JavaScript.

```
everyone(this) { function stackOverFlow(welcome[2]);}
```

Good Luck

Comment: How [intensive](http://www.onelook.com/?w=for%20all%20intents%20and%20purposes&ls=a) are your purposes? ;)

Comment: "all intensive purposes" means "any use of" in American.  I just can't get away from my native tounge.  lol  Besides brackets are for the final four or World Cup betting pools.  http://www.gosylvester.com/TournamentPrototype.aspx

Comment: "For all intensive purposes" in an [eggcorn](http://www.onelook.com/?w=eggcorn&ls=a) which I've seen only fairly recently, though apparently [it's been around since the '80s](http://www.word-detective.com/2009/01/intensive-purposes/).

Comment: It should be "for all intents and purposes"

Answer (score -6):

This has nothing to do with internationalization.

- "brackets" is a colloquialism used when describing written English;
- "parenthesis", in all branches of English, is the correct formal term for not only the symbology (or, incorrectly, "parentheses" in pairs) but also the linguistic construct and, as such, is the appropriate term to use when describing the use of `()` in computer program source code.

In short, your usage was *wrong*, not *different*. :)

Comment: Variables passed to a function are hardly parenthetical by any reasonable definition. ;)