# Spelling corrections and incorrect punctuation changes - how to reverse someone's changes

Tags: discussion

I've recently had a question/answer of mine modified, of which I have no ability to state that the changes are not appropriate.

First question:

1. I'm Australian. So I use Australian spelling. Someone has reformatted my question using American words. I would think this is something that should not be cause for an update to a question. Am I correct?
2. The question I raised was easy to comprehend, however the editor felt that it could be formatted better. I cannot see justification in reformatting my question, other than possibly trying to gain more points for performing reviews. Is there a guide on when someone should reformat/reword a question?
3. Punctuation changes like capitalising the first word after a comma in a sentence is AFAIK incorrect, however this was done. I appear to have no recourse. In light of the other changes, shouldn't the original author be able to contest the changes made?

The question and changes are:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8726526

https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/19603869/3

The first one appears to be just point scoring, changes that I would reject. The second one is very subjective, I would argue that the original text was readable and clear, not IMHO grounds to modify. Trying to format questions like English literature pieces would to me be beyond the grounds to justify a change.

Please clarify if my view of the events are incorrect (explaining why, if they are) and how I can revert the changes. I'm aware I can edit and put in the original text, hoping that there is an easier mechanism.

Comment: There is a rollback link in the revision list, though I don't think it warrants a rollback in this case.

Comment: The first change is the removal of one space, the incorrect capitalisation of a word and the americanisation of another. The second was purely based on opinion. I would have thought that the first one is wrong, and the second one is unjustified.

Comment: Meh. The suggestion is annoying enough that I'd look through the users edits and if they're doing it elsewhere ask them to stop. Stephen's edit looks like an alright one though and fixes all the issues caused by the suggestion.

Comment: Possibly Meh for you, however it comes down to the user experience. If I correct a person's question then I'm careful to only change what must be changed to add clarity or correct bad English. Being notified of changes and then seeing that they're of this nature borders on insulting.

Comment: I think you're overreacting with "insulting". There's actually no harm that's been done, you have the option to rollback as explained above but I don't see the point. The edit that's been made makes the post a minuscule amount easier to read and that's not a bad thing.

Comment: I have no option to rollback, I'm not sure what this option is. In regards to insulting, I stated "borders on", in the context of user experience. When B changes what A wrote then this brings into question the quality of what A wrote from the viewpoint of A. A Part of UX is emotions, people who have their text modified can feel emotional, especially if there is no apparent recourse.

Comment: It's funny, because in the first link above, a capital However is not correct in any means. _Technically_, it should be `process; however, ` But I would not make such an edit. Your original post was perfectly fine.

Comment: Interesting that I've now received two down votes for the question all since this happened. I'm not sure why I'm receiving down votes other than because of this question.

Comment: I get so mad when someone AmericaniZes my words in an edit without actually doing anything helpful. TBH even if they do add helpful edits, the AmericanIZATION of anything I write pisses me off...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. Yes, you're fine in this assertion.  Everyone spells English words differently, and both forms ("realized"/"realised") are acceptable.  An edit that only changes this isn't sufficient to be considered an edit in my book.
2. There's not really a formal guide, but the goal should be to make the post clearer than the way it was found.  For example,  [the fourth revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/19603869/4) reads a bit clearer to me than [your original post](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/19603869/1).

   The editor may have done this just for the points, but in actuality it was the result of [a reviewer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/558721/stephen) selecting "Improve Edit".  It is on them that the fault lies; this edit should *not* have been approved.
3. The only means to contest you would have had is to roll back the edit and/or leave a comment to the editor (as editors can be @named in comments).  If it persisted -- that is, they kept making the same stupid edit -- then you could roll back and flag for moderator attention.

Comment: You need to remove the last sentence of your first point. The internetz been over this multiple times and there's no reason to change anyone's spelling just 'cause you spell it slightly differently - no matter the circumstances. If a post has been written in, say, AmE it should stay there.

Comment: Is 'rollback' restricted?

Comment: See also http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252504/458741 and http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/23869/179419 for the English discussions

Comment: @Metalskin:  I believe as the original poster, you should be able to roll back the content.  I wouldn't recommend it in this case since there's a rather nice edit already present on your question.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17038/179419 @metal.

Comment: @Ben:  Considering that we're talking only about a single post, I'm actually *agreeing* with and reinforcing the first point.  Since we're not talking about tags, I don't feel the value to mention that point - but it is an interesting case to think about.  It's also dirt old, so I wonder if Shog still feels the same way about it.

Comment: @Makoto: I cannot see the rollback option sorry. 

I do agree that the last mod is fine, my question was more about understand the processes for edits than trying to know how to roll it back.

Comment: @Metalskin http://i.imgur.com/NHn1oht.png

Comment: Don't see the options sorry. Just found out that if I go off the review tab and back onto it, I get a message saying I need 2K reputation to view it. So maybe those options are only available if you have > 2K rep.

Answer (score 8):

Posting this as an answer as to show screen shots.  Metalskin If you click on "edited date"

[image]

Then you are brought to the [revision history page](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19603869/revisions).  Once there on each revision header there is a rollback option.

[image]

As the creator of the post you have full control of all edits that happen to your post and can reject suggestions and rollback to previous revisions.

Comment: Ahh thank you, I've found it now. I was flowing from the notification of the change, I didn't realise there was another way to get to the edit history. Thanks again.