# There are more important things on which to take a stand

Tags: discussion

I am extremely upset by the continuous actions of the Saudi Arabian government. It is immoral, unethical, morally repugnant and fundamentally anti-humanitarian.

The use of anti-Jewish, anti-Christian propaganda in school textbooks.
The inability of opposition religions to freely operate in the country, and the inability of opposition political ideals to freely operate in the country, both at pain of death.

All public gatherings, including peaceful demonstrations, remained prohibited under an order issued by the Ministry of the Interior in 2011. Those who sought to defy the ban faced arrest, prosecution and imprisonment on charges such as “inciting people against the authorities”. In March last year, the government warned that it would arrest and prosecute anyone who publicly criticized Saudi Arabia’s military actions in Yemen; in November last year, the Ministry of Justice was reported to have said it would sue anyone who compared Saudi Arabia’s justice system to that operated by IS.

Most of all, any country that implements the death penalty for the 'non-crime' of apostasy is committing a terrible crime against humanity and is carving up the world into us vs. them, building walls, and demonizing religions, nations, and refugees and is of course, both morally repugnant and counterproductive, and it goes so much against the spirit of Stack Overflow that as a community we must speak out.

Comment: We get the point. ---

Comment: Another ill-conceived attempt to make an point... This question was obviously not created in good faith.

Comment: The fact that it is immediately put on hold is actually the point. The original post hurt, and the response to this one has left me no choice but to request my profile be deleted. I certainly won't use or contribute to any stack exchange site again.

Comment: Ah, I now understand the reason for this post, see linked post: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342440/time-to-take-a-stand

Comment: Yes, this is a serious problem, too, and something that we *do* need to take a stand on. One major difference, though, is that Stack Overflow is a company headquartered in the United States, and thus the policies of that government have an immediate and real impact on Stack Overflow as a company. Furthermore, Stack Overflow as a company headquartered in the US, and employing US residents, is in *a real position to actually do something* about US policy, whereas we're not in any real position to do anything about the human rights violations in Saudi Arabia. You've my vote, but it doesn't count.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because how much I like having all kind of topics which I might or might not have to take a stand on, the post from Joel, CEO of Stack Overflow, Inc. is hopefully an one of and that hope is being discussed in at least one new MSO post and one on MSE and on top of that a complete chat room with all kind of balanced opinions. Before we take next stands, let's wait for the outcome on the other discussions.

Comment: Like it or not, what U.S. does influences the whole world through the media. There are worst things in the word than Trump's "ban on muslims", but the **do not influence** the rest of the world as much.

Comment: @rene It is not a one off though.  We celebrated the overturning of gay marriage bans (woot) and now we are rallying against trumps immigration policies (woot again).  My takeaway from this is that SO does not take a stand unless of course upper management has a stake, then to hell with the rules, they want to say something.  I have nothing against what they are talking about I just do not think they are talking about it in the right place.

Comment: "the response to this one has left me no choice but to request my profile be deleted" As a protest to your protest self-deletion, I will double down and answer twice as many answers as before. Also I think you might be overreacting a bit. CEOs get preferential treatment, no biggie if you ask me.

Comment: @NathanOliver yeah, true and there are even a few more. Point taken

Comment: @meagar Why does this need to to be closed but you reopened the other question?

Comment: @meagar Please explain why this is off-topic while the other question is not.

Comment: @NathanOliver Feel free to [start reading](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/134324/discussion-on-question-by-joel-spolsky-time-to-take-a-stand) but the tl;dr is pretty obvious: Joel is the CEO of this platform. Yes, he gets special treatment. No, we're not turning meta into a political platform where everybody gets to post whatever they want about whatever happens to be upsetting them in the world. Pretty obvious stuff.

Comment: *"Joel is the CEO of this platform. Yes, he gets special treatment."* @meagar ... wouldn't it be far easier to just move Joel's post and avoid that secondary hot potato here on MSO?

Comment: @Bart Yes, it would, and as soon as Joel or an SO employee wants to do that they will. In the mean time, Joel has chosen to make a statement on this site and both he and multiple SO employees have demonstrated that they intend to keep the question here, and keep it open. Constructive actions might include contributing to the [existing meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342480/should-time-to-take-a-stand-question-be-closed-moved), not making new posts that you *know* are off-topic here.

Comment: @meagar If we are okay with certain people get special treatment then fine.  I for one am not a fan of that.  What ever happen to judge a post on content, not the user?

Comment: It's pretty paradoxical, that the CEO of the *site* violates the *sites* policies.

Comment: @NathanOliver It doesn't sit well with me either, but again: Joel is the CEO, and he chose *this site* to make his statement. That doesn't suddenly mean that SO is not a *moderated community* with strict standards for what is on and off topic. Allowing one special case by the **CEO** does not invalidate all of our policy.

Comment: @RaisingAgent Discussed ad nauseum in https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134324/discussion-on-question-by-joel-spolsky-time-to-take-a-stand

Comment: @meagar ikr, I'm present there since a couple of hours. It's *amusing*

Comment: @meagar Allowing one special case because he is the CEO IS the problem

Comment: @meagar But it isn't one.  This is the second in my short time here.  Right now we are at about one a year.  Is this going to keep going?  Is this going to increase?  I just find it disenfranchising that all the things that get preached all the sudden get ignored because of who the OP is.  I hate to say it but the actions here really remind me of trump, that is the  *I hear your opinion but I don't care, I have a soap box and I'm going to use it*.

Comment: @NathanOliver "What ever happen to judge a post on content, not the user?" I guess the owners of StackOverflow Inc. will decide what happens to this. Could be they declare it to a rule with some notable exceptions. Or maybe Joel gets fired. Maybe Trump buys them, just to show how he deals with resistance. Nobody knows. But rules can have exceptions of course. They are just more complicated rules then.

Comment: "Allowing one special case because he is the CEO IS the problem" Not a very big problem then. There is only one CEO. However that would make a good question: "Should the CEO be granted this privilege?" would be right to the point. I think nobody asked that so far.

Comment: @NathanOliver Good questions, but posting off-topic questions on meta isn't the answer.

Comment: @RaisingAgent "It's pretty paradoxical, that the CEO of the site violates the sites policies" You mean it's like the government breaking the law? Well, it's not [unhear of](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watergate_scandal). Site policies are less binding than laws though.

Comment: @meagar, no it does not invalidate .. right ! May I post a question with all those topics to help people have better "understanding" of the issue, in fact i just want a big list where I can cast my close vote! Because It's off topics Primary opinion based. and this is the 4th post about it.

Comment: http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/24622/what-fallacy-dismisses-problems-by-presenting-bigger-problems

Comment: @random https://yourlogicalfallacyis.com/the-fallacy-fallacy

Comment: *Good questions, but posting off-topic questions on meta isn't the answer.* This is getting ridiculous, @meagar, since that's exactly the reason why we tried to get Joel's question closed. You're basically saying the CEO has a free pass to post everything he damn well wishes here, without the community having any say in the matter. Whatever happened to "site run and policed by *you*, the community"? What if Joel wants to advocate, I don't know, hunting whales next year, will we still be supposed to sit, endure and say nothing?

Comment: @random I know the fallacy well. I did not say one problem is greater than another. I said there are more important things on which to take a stand.

Comment: The site is still run by the community, but the staff and CEO still can dictate how the site is run, or what is posted

Comment: There may be other issues to take a stand on, but this is the issue SE have chosen to take a stand on at this time

Comment: @random, well, it is not actually run by the community then. We just have to accept it. Or leave. Pick your poison.

Comment: Today has proven that the site is not run by the community. The community merely contribute to a commercial vehicle run by businessmen who are prepared to use it as a vehicle to represent their own political opinion [in at least one example, possibly two with one of the answers to another comment]

Comment: Today didn't prove anything different to what the site started out with. They the staff run a site and the community help shape it, but make no mistake it was never wholly in the hands of the users

Comment: @random Agreed! - I have already submitted my leave request as I feel it personally untenable to contribute any longer. I know I'm only a teeny tiny part of it and completely unimportant, but it still hurts that the reason why has nothing to do with SO rules or vision.

Comment: "...but it still hurts that the reason why has nothing to do with SO rules or vision." That sounds a bit like you writing your own epitaph. I would like to ask yout not to leave for that reason mostly because I think you are overreacting. I guess you have a point somewhere but maybe less than you think you have. All in all it might be better to sleep a bit over it. Shouting loudly good bye (especially in internet communities) is likely not having the effect you desire it to have.

Comment: I do not wish to have an effect. I leave here for the same reason I have resigned from my current job. On principle.

Comment: And you want to make sure as many people know about it as you possibly can on the way out; that's why you posted this. Anyone seen those South Park episodes about people leaving social media?

Comment: @KimberleyBarrass, if you feel like you need to leave, leave. Nobody is stopping you. Right now it just seems that what you want is rise a stink and complain on the same platform that you decry as not giving you a voice. You wouldn't be the first person to stop using a product/service because you disagreed with something the owners/management did, but at least you are given the opportunity to air your grievances right here, which is not something you'll get in many other situations. Good luck in ExpertSexChange.com or whatever Q&A you'll want to give your patronage next. ;)

Comment: All I see is a legitimate point made as to why Joel's post should have been closed, and responses to everyone trying to defend his post. Everyone should be aware that Joel is obviously given special treatment as the CEO, so that they can decide if they want to continue being a part of the community.

Comment: I've [clarified our position on this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342480/should-the-time-to-take-a-stand-question-be-closed-moved/342675#342675) on the question asking what should be done with Joel's post. As employees, if we see something that threatens to keep you from us, or us from you, we're going to speak out about it through the company's voice, and we need to do that here on our own platform. However, we heard and learned quite a lot yesterday, so we will be doing things a bit differently.

Comment: @TimPost There's a lot keeping developers/potential developers from Stack Exchange. Lack of Internet access due to geographical location, poor economic state, and great firewalls. Where do we draw the line? Why is a temporary halt in immigration in one country so much worse than the pre-existing conditions in many other countries that it deserves a mention and not others?

Comment: Nit: it should be "morally repugnant and frankly stupid" [as in the original](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/342440/1) All political rhetoric, even from micro celebrities, must be polemic.  They need to scrap the work on the new layout and get to work adding a crawl to the bottom of the screen: "What Joel is thinking right now....".

Comment: People taking a stand against people taking a stand against people taking a stand..

Comment: this appears to have nothing to do with SO

Comment: @Tommy Part of me wants to cast a vote saying "I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of [WP:POINT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Do_not_disrupt_Wikipedia_to_illustrate_a_point)", but I don't have the heart to do that.

Comment: @KimberleyBarrass Your statement beginning with "Today has proven..." is entirely true. What confuses me is why anyone was ever under the illusion it would be any other way. Did anyone *really* think that their having written and answered some questions gave them a comparable stake in, or control over, the political stance of the company as employees and shareholders had?

Comment: @CodyGray And that is indeed the problem. No matter how Joel tried to make it sound as if SO should stand up against Trump as being an *international community*, the main motive is because SO is a *USA company*. Other issues that might be as important to the community, but not to the company, don't get this platform which this question painstakingly proves. Anyway I made a suggestion on The Other thread that might enable SO to actually make a stand in Saudi Arabia too, at least more than these Meta posts.

Comment: @meagar: _"Allowing one special case by the CEO does not invalidate all of our policy"_ Sorry, yes, it does. And it's a slap in the face to all of us who spend considerable time helping you guys to enforce those policies.

Comment: @duplode no I literally don't understand what this post has anything to do with stack overflow. I must be missing some massive context because stack overflow is only mentioned in the last sentence of the OP's question and the post appears to be a political rant.

Comment: @Tommy This question is a protest against the existence of [this other question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/342440/2751851).

Comment: @duplode how was I supposed to know that, nothing in the question links to that!

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara: _"Another ill-conceived attempt to make an point... This question was obviously not created in good faith"_ Site rules says **assume good faith**. Although apparently we're not following the site rules any more :)

Comment: @Tommy: You were supposed to know because duplode just told you :)

Comment: @Tommy You weren't -- it's just that a large part of Meta has been up in arms because of it since Saturday (cf. the [massive](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/342480/2751851) [amounts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/342539/2751851) [of ink](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/134324) spilled about it).

Comment: @duplode I re-iterate my vote to close.

Comment: I am waiting for the "Should the 'There are more important things on which to take a stand' question be closed / locked?" question.

Comment: @Tommy I would vote to close this too, except that the precedent has been set by no less than the CEO to keep these sorts of questions open ;)

Comment: Only so much I could to today. I'm locking this because the last thing we need is a close / reopen war. Hoped to talk about this today but folks are kinda mad all over the place, and I need to actually sleep a little :) I'm posting a _lot_ more once I'm rested and caffeinated.