# Am I being too pedantic with spelling in reviewing question titles?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

One of my edits was rejected: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9389227. I changed the title from:

> Dependant Template Compiles with Visual Studio, fails clang/gcc

To

> Dependent Template Compiles with Visual Studio, but fails with clang/gcc

The main purpose of the edit was the change from "dependant" to "dependent", and I would never have made the edit to change "fails clang/gcc" to "but fails with clang/gcc" (as that doesn't make the question easier to find). But on that point, I made the edit because I believed it ***would*** make the question easier to find, and it was the reason it was rejected. I also felt I wasn't able to change anything else in the question to improve it as I found it well-written.

*Dependant* and *dependent* are two different words, although some sites make mention they do mean the same thing and that dependant is an alternate spelling for dependent. According to [this answer on Grammar SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11310/what-is-the-correct-spelling-of-dependent-which-preposition-should-follow-it) *dependant* isn't even used in American English, and means something entirely different in British English.

Regardless, looking up each on Stack Overflow gives two different results and *dependant*, if accepted, is considered the less common spelling.

So:

- *Dependant* is not considered a word in American English (which might explain why Chrome keeps putting a red squiggly line under it)
- If it *is* considered a word in American English, it's considered a more rare variation
- *Dependant* means something entirely different in British English
- Both give completely different search results on Stack Overflow
- The error mentioned in the question used "dependent"

By these merits: shouldn't changing *dependant* to *dependent* make the question easier to find, or am I being too pedantic?

Comment: Also consider that your rejection was finalized by the OP; sometimes people get touchy about editing (and/or their right to spell or write badly).

Comment: and/or there write to mispell or right badly

Comment: I as non-native speaker am curious what dependant means in british english. Can you explain this difference? Thx

Comment: @LeosLiterak: in British English "dependant" is a noun (a gerund formed from the verb "to depend") while "dependent" is the adjective. Apparently in American English "dependent" is used for both the noun and adjective forms (and thus "dependant" does not exist, but maybe in practice it's understood).

Comment: I don't usually edit questions just to correct a typo, but I do it for question titles, because spelling in the title is important for search results. I would even use American spelling in my own question titles (even if I use British spelling in the question text) to improve search visibility. I think correcting a title always makes sense, however minor the edit.

Comment: You could have finished off the capitalization too

Comment: If I may be pedantic: you're missing the question mark in your title.

Comment: More pedanticity... the comma should be removed.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

After reading your explanation I think your edit makes sense and should have been accepted.

However, you should consider that to someone who is not a native (nor an expert) English speaker it really looks like you are being pedantic, and possibly fighting some British-English vs American-English war (like "grey" instead of "gray"), [which is not encouraged](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252504/3982001). I, for one, would have fallen flat here. Therefore, since the change *appears* trivial but *is* substantial, I would have pointed that out in the edit comment. Something like

> Fixed spelling: "dependant" has a different meaning and it's used incorrectly here

And, assuming there is enough space, even a link to the question on English SE which you have put here.

I think it would have greatly increased the chances of it being accepted.

Comment: Very good answer. In general, I prefer writing "copyediting" rather than "fixing spelling" or "fixing grammar" in edit summaries. That way, the intent of the edit is conveyed in a far less pointed way. This specific case is a little unusual, and there is a point in being less vague given how easy it is to overlook the issue. A wat of putting it without the "fixed spelling" might be: "*dependent* fits better as an adjective here".

Comment: You are completely correct, and I overlooked why the edit would be rejected by someone who may not be familiar with the two terms. In the future, I'll be sure to be as clear as possible in my edit summary. Thank you for eye-opening answer!

Comment: @duplode Why is "copyediting" more polite than "fixing spelling" (please explain for a non-native English speaker)? The description [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_editing) says it's basically the same, but less specific.

Comment: @anatolyg "Copyediting" covers grammar and spelling fixes, but also formatting improvements, sentence flow adjustments and other things that make a post easier to read. I don't think "fixing spelling" is impolite in and of itself, but it is more likely to be taken by an OP as drawing attention to a perceived lack of English skills, and with the cost of the change being so low I prefer avoiding that. Furthermore, it is very often the case that other readability improvements are done along with the spelling and grammar fixes, making "copyediting" even more appropriate as a summary.

Comment: In this context *dependant* is clearly a misspelling, not an American English vs. British English thing. It is a wowel substitution (or whatever it is called) and mainly made by Americans (due to how words are pronounced). Other examples are *persistance*, *accessability*, ***definately***, *independant*, recommandation, *recomand*, and *compatablitiy* (the correct spelling is *persistence*, *accessibility*, ***definitely***, *independent*, *recommendation*, *recommend*, and *compatibility*, respectively).

Comment: (Unrelated: *definitely* has its own problems - these have been observed in the wild: *definately*, *deffinetely*, *definally*, *definately*, *definatly*, *definetely*, *definetly*, *definiately*, *definitetly*, *definitly*, *definively*, *defintly*, *defninitely*, *denitely*. See also [http://d-e-f-i-n-i-t-e-l-y.com/](http://d-e-f-i-n-i-t-e-l-y.com/).)

Answer (score 21):

I fully agree with your appraisal; the misspelling here would likely make Google searches less likely to find this question (though it's possible it would overlook the misspelling). There was nothing else in the post obviously worthy of changing.

The rejection was likely because the edit *was* small; it's just one of the rare cases where a small edit is warranted. I went ahead and applied your new title. Keep up the good work!

Comment: Try this on Google (also searching for some news on spelling within the Google search engine) and you will realise that this is not true. Google will treat all spellings with the same weight, otherwise US links would appear above UK links just because they are spelt how Google likes it

Comment: US links will appear about UK links because, all else being equal, your search history indicates you are US centric or you are geolocated in the US.

Answer (score 4):

Good change, but it *looks like* minor edit.

I'd say "Fixed title to match error message" would not cause any objections.

With current generic description (or any description going into discussion why particular spelling should be used in "proper English") I would expect it to be rejected as minor, or better yet "reject and edit" to keep the change and send subtle message to avoid minor edits.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than resorting to a dictionary or English language usage question, go directly to the only source that matters for terminology in programming questions: The language standard.

[image]

If your edit comment had mentioned "This is spelled *dependent*, see C++ Standard, section 14.6.2", the reviewers who rejected the edit would be sitting in review-ban timeout right now.

Comment: I really like this! Ultimately it doesn't matter what "dependant" means in American or British English, it matters what it means in C++ (or to a specific compiler). I initially felt this would only work if I was familiar with a language (I'm familiar with C++ so I knew dependant was wrong), but I don't think I'd edit a Python (to which I have no knowledge) question that used dependant without some research into making sure it didn't mean anything,

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this change is that it is way too minor. It is true there is a spelling mistake, even though I (as a Brit) understand what they mean by "dependant" it is not the correct use of the word (nor in fact the correct word).

However, to clear this up a bit (and to stop you just editing questions to be only one form of English), the only standard for *which* English variant is used is in fact within the tags ( [What should the standard spelling be - British or US?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23869/what-should-the-standard-spelling-be-british-or-us#comment49465_23872) ) so that is something to bear in mind, not saying you would make edits to just change UK to US.

As for Google: spelling makes no difference. They use a dictionary composed by users to keep track of over 30 million (unfortunately, I cannot seem to find the link that Google wrote about this when searching Google...ironically) spelling mistakes ranking them the same.

I mean imagine a US link out ranking a UK link just because of a language difference? SEO simply does not work like that.

You must also remember that in a phrase most engines will remove some stop words like "but" and "with". It is normally dependent upon case, for example: not when searching for "The Who" (where the stop word is important). As an example, this is a common list of words removed from Solr and other FTS techs by default http://xpo6.com/list-of-english-stop-words/. Not only that but any good search engine will search across the entire title so adding the expletives doesn't really help.

Since the title makes sense right now I just don't see the point in the edit to make it more complex and add words that are normally considered weightless in search.

As such I, personally, would have rejected your changes as "too minor" (due to the expletives in the title) and fixed the spelling mistake myself.

Comment: Your argument is reasonable, and I understand why minor edits are frowned upon, but I'm not sure I agree. Regardless of SEO, the title is the most visible part of a Q&A. The way I see it, any edit that makes a title substantially cleaner or more readable is not minor enough to be rejected.

Comment: @duplode hmm, I would argue that adding the expletives makes the title harder to read. The words are noise (like Hello or Thanks on questions), but that comes down to personal preference I guess.

Comment: Proper <s>grammar</s> sentence construction can make a sentence easier to parse. In this example, the "but... with" makes it instantly obvious "clang/gcc" is in direct contrast with "Visual Studio". I find the edited version far easier to read.

Comment: @duplode well, the comma is there which means it is not actually incorrect

Comment: @duplode in fact actually "but" does not normally have a comma before it, definitely not in that modified title so actually the edit is grammatically incorrect

Comment: On the other hand, the missing "with" breaks parallelism of the coordinated sentences.

Comment: @duplode true, maybe omit "but" and add "with"?

Comment: @duplode mind you if we were to be really pedantic: technically "with" is the wrong word in the first place...this is the problem when you allow people to make edits based on the finer points of grammar `:/`

Comment: It seems the comma is [optional but allowed](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/28277/128913) though.

Comment: @duplode I am not sure about that answer. The BBC site (which I consider to be slightly authoritative since I am UK English) actually sides with the answer below the accepted one. The guy who linked it did not actually read what he was linking.

Comment: With regards to "dependant" vs "dependent" in Google and other big search engines, I have no doubts (plus you've confirmed) that Google is able to predict the correct usage; however, Stack Overflow's search cannot. Searching Stack Overflow for dependant and dependent gives different results. I generally don't go overboard with grammatical fixes if I feel it doesn't make the question or sentence easier to read (which is more important than proper grammar). Case in point: I didn't add a question mark to this question. If my edit had been rejected and updated to be more grammatical I'd understand

Comment: @Tas yes, I would have fixed the spelling for SO search, since that search is primitive, however, the real visibility problem is with mostly Google since 98% of searching occurs there and people seemed to think Google is primitive in it's working. Tbh your edit being rejected might be down to even the time of day you did it, to one set of reviewers they would reject, another they would accept. Your non spelling check edits were very opinionated in terms of reviewing