# What's wrong with this edit suggestion?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20730639

Change content:

1. Changed subject to from a more general "why is it the way it is" to be specifically about the contents of the question "why is it a behaviour not a protocol?"
2. Corrected the spelling for a specific elixir keyword "behaviour" to use the British spelling (this was actually changed from the correct term to the incorrect one in a previous edit)
3. Removed the phrase "I am relatively new to Elixir".

Is there a problem with these changes, or is it that they are not substantial enough? I'm struggling to correlate the reject reason:

> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read,
>   easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either
>   completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

with the changes in this case. To me it makes it more accurate and and easier to find.

Comment: My guess is that because that keyword is not formatted as code, reviewers thought that change #2 was just a style preference change. We aren't supposed to be making American/British spelling changes at all, at least not when it is normal text.

Comment: @BSMP - If it is a keyword, then that isn't an American/British spelling change.  It is a technical correction.

Comment: @StephenC I am not disputing that. I am pointing out that because it is not formatted like code the reviewers likely didn't realize it was a keyword. They *thought* it was a style change.

Comment: @AdamMillerchip Are you sure that "behaviour" is an actual keyword (i.e. something that is actually used as code as a part of the language)? A brief look through the [Elixir documentation](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/typespecs-and-behaviours.html) indicates that the actual keyword is `@behaviour`, whereas the English word "behaviour" is used to describe a concept similar to interfaces. However, I'm not at all familiar with Elixir, so my brief scan thought the docs could have been misleading.

Comment: I've concluded that there wasn't actually anything wrong with my edit, and the reviewers rejected it in error. :-) If I get 2k rep maybe I'll make the change again.

Answer (score 8):

I would suggest that:

> Don't change spellings from British -> US or Vice/Versa.

These are meaningless changes.  Just noise.  Especially if you are going to make them in the direction you did, given that SO is a US website.

You list three changes, but in two of them you changed ambiguous spellings.  The only completely obvious change was the removal of the valueless greeting thingy.  So three changes.  One good, one pointless, and one muddled by the worthless spelling change.  I can easily see how that would be weighed as 1 good, 2 bad, equals NO.

Comment: Behaviour is a keyword in Elixir that uses British spelling. Using American spelling is incorrect. This is not a preference change, but a correction. Similar to talking about the Java class called Color by referring to it as Colour would be wrong.

Comment: Cool, but...  The edits were not in a code section so were not obviously strictly needed.

Comment: Ok I can understand that, thanks. It's inconsistent that a previous edit already changed to the American spelling from the OP's spelling though.

Comment: About the first change. This was not a spelling change, but a clarification of the subject to what was in the content.

Comment: @adammillerchip That edit was done by someone with over 2K rep so their edit wasn't reviewed. They probably don't know that British/American spelling conversions aren't something we should be doing. It's not a rule in the help center but something that's been discussed on Meta. (That or they didn't realize it was a legitimate spelling.)

Comment: @BSMP: Depending on the context they could also be doing it to maintain consistency in the post. And I personally don't have a problem with users making those edits for that purpose when those edits don't need to undergo review, unless they're editing so many posts at once as to clutter up the front page.

Comment: @AdamMillerchip: In this case, I'd use formatting such as `Behaviour` to make it clear that this is *code*, not a regular word.

Comment: The fact that SO is supposedly a US site because its servers are there is deeply irrelevant, and possibly insulting, to everyone not in the US. This is an international website, if you want to consider it as a US website, then block its access for everyone else. Rejecting an edit because of that makes no sense, and is much more worthless than the original rewriting.

Comment: @MatthieuM. How so? It was literally mentioned in the edit summary that "behaviour" is the way Elixir uses it. There is no need to format it at code.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier: It makes it clearer for everyone, including future readers which will not check the edit history, and it makes sure that even if reviewers do not read the summary they'll that something is special. It's a win-win as far as I am concerned.

Comment: If you say so @Matthieu. I find it disheartening that we need take into consideration reviewers that do not read the summary. That's like, the very basis of reviewing edits. Future readers will also not be affected either way, they're looking at a complete post, there being a "u" or not makes no difference. In this case, the reviewers should have seen the case for adding it, *and* it was part of a larger edit. None of the reasons make sense.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier: I find it disheartening too :(

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is with changing between natural spelling and american spelling. There is a [de-facto rule](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252503/are-british-international-english-terms-acceptable-e-g-brackets-instead-of) not to make such edits.

Personally I consider your edit correct (not because it changes to British spelling, but because it undoes a previous harmful edit and returns a Keyword to it's correct value). However because of this de-facto rule, rejecting the edit was the correct action (your edit comment did not mention its role as a keyword so many reviewers would not be aware)

My approach for such cases would be to instead rollback the harmful edit and leave a suitable comment as to why, to avoid beginning a rollback war

Comment: I didn't specifically say keyword, but I did say "Elixir uses that spelling". I think the rejecters were over-zealous in this case and misunderstood the content of the edit, possibly just seeing the spelling change. Specifically reverting the old edit is a good idea, but the primary change was the title wording which wasn't in a previous edit, and I also only noticed that after it was rejected and I investigated in more detail.

Comment: This does not apply, as the change was indeed `"[...] part of wider edits to make improvements to the post."` (from the de-facto answer).