# Minor tag wiki edit rejected

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits, tag-wiki

My [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/26695827) of the Python tag wiki was rejected for the following generic reason:

> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

Now, I'm not here to complain. I'd like to know how I can prevent this going forward as I still would like to help where I can around SO. I've looked at related Meta questions and I can see why most of them were rejected; e.g. 'polishing the unsatisfactory', but this is different because the Python wiki is pretty well composed.

My current understanding is that minor edits; such as my suggestion, are **discouraged** for questions and answers, which makes sense as those are volatile in the sense that they could disappear on a whim. However, the tag wiki is a more persistent brief for established tags. Therefore, it would seem logical to me that perfecting that text is desirable where it does not harm readability. After all, it's a community-driven wiki.

The rejection reason seems to suggest that unless an edit makes a substantial difference, it should be rejected. This mindset really harks back to the '[mean](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/)' days of SO as, in my opinion, while the edit does not do *much* for the tag, it certainly isn't detrimental to it and subjectively *is* an improvement; albeit if only for minor grammatical amendments and slight revisions. I still took the time to go through it and make the edits.

Really, my question boils down to: is SO a better place for having rejected the minor edit? And should I not suggest edits that don't change the text fundamentally in the future?

**Edit**
I see the issue with my suggestion and I'm grateful to those who reviewed it and agree with it being rejected. My question now is, if the issues with the suggestion were fixed and it was resubmitted, would it be rejected for being too minor?

Comment: One thing to think about is that you're suggesting edits to a high profile document. It has been viewed 116656 times. One should use extreme care when suggesting edits.

Comment: @IanCampbell Good point and I agree, I thought I had been careful but clearly not as good as I thought!

Comment: Note that "dialog" is an alternate spelling of "dialogue" that is used in North America and in some of the largest UI libraries. Stack Overflow generally frowns on edits that change from one dialect's spelling to another. See [Are British/International English terms acceptable? (e.g. 'brackets' instead of 'parentheses')](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252503/215552)

Comment: @HereticMonkey Yeah, I noticed that soon after Cody pointed out the mistakes, see my Edit to the question :)

Comment: As someone who took a chainsaw to another bloated tag wiki, this one needs the same treatment. It's TL;DR as is

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some of your changes were improvements; others were regressions. I would have rejected that edit, too. Not for being too minor, but for introducing nearly as many grammatical errors as it fixed.

And...please do not attempt to claim that having an edit rejected is somehow "mean" or "unwelcoming". The site has peer review for a reason. Your coworkers are not evil people who hate you and want you to fail because they raise concerns during a code review.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to suggest that this was rejected maliciously because I know it wasn't. Merely that the default reason is, in my opinion, not particularly helpful or welcoming.

Comment: That's not the "default" reason; it's one of the options that reviewers can choose from. There's absolutely nothing unwelcoming about indicating that a particular edit does not make a substantial improvement.

Comment: Default as in they didn't write it, the wrong choice of words I guess. Do you think it was rejected for regressions or no substantial improvement?

Comment: I find it hard to distinguish between the two. Some fixes - some regressions = no significant improvement.