# Can I remove the Hot Meta Posts section from my view in SO?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, meta, community-bulletin, site-crossover

Most of the questions on Meta seem to be answerable with some simple common sense.

This really annoys me and i'd like to not see it.

I have tried simply ignoring it but it draws me in like a bad troll every time.

Please allow me to opt out and instead just see popular questions for Stack Overflow itself.

And no, the Irony is not missed on me here.

Comment: No, you can't. See this [answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252470/2982225)

Comment: I can understand the rationale behind. Not every user is so keen on meta discussions. Using an adblocker with class "module community-bulletin" you could do it yourself but a site wide opt-out might be just the extra service that is needed.

Comment: Stack Exchange is not going to add an option for *every little tweak you could possibly make*. If it bothers you, use a userscript or add the div to your adblocker.

Comment: "Most of the questions on meta seem to be answerable with some simple common sense" - Well, here's the simple, common sense answer to this question: There would be a whole heap of problems with an "official" way to do this (how do you opt out and back in? how is this setting saved? most importantly, how to deal with the hundreds of other things people want hidden, as a precedent for hiding things would now have been set?). The benefit for the few users who care enough to hide it is far outweighted by the potential issues. Just use an userscript, custom stylesheet or your adblocker.

Comment: If common sense was actually common, we could just shut down meta and solve the whole problem at its root. Buuuut...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a user script to take it out. However, while the majority of what you see might seem uninteresting, it's there for a very specific reason. Contests, give-aways, important notices about changes and the like tend to be posted there. We advertise planned outages *much* further in advance on meta than we do on the main site, for instance.

It's a *very* small amount of real estate on the screen *and* an important channel to let folks know about things that affect the community in which they participate, so we're extremely unlikely to provide a means of hiding it.

Comment: "*It's a very small amount of real estate on the screen*" - it is not THAT small.  On my screen, it stretches the entire height of my browser even when maximized. The next item on my sidebar, "Watched Tags", is almost completely offscreen, only the 1st line of tags is visible without scrolling (I have 5 lines of tags).