# Can I hide the "Hot Network Questions"?

Tags: support, hot-questions

I use StackOverflow a lot when working, and many times I got distracted by the Hot Network Questions (Specially those from SciFi).

[image: interesting hot network questions]

Is there any way I could disable that block from my account settings? Is it okay if I use a plugin like adblock to remove that block?

Comment: "_Is it okay if I use a plugin like adblock to remove that block?_" Sure. Should be really easy actually.

Comment: @JonasCz Yes, it's. But, I think that I could remember some reading at some site policies (Not on SE) that using ad blocking plugins was forbidden

Comment: Certain StackOverflow execs are in disagreement. Just focus on yo' work !!

Comment: It is not practically possible to prevent people from blocking ads.  Forbidding it is a waste of everyone's time.

Comment: @Kevin - But adblock does *not* block these "hot questions" anyway as they are static content, not ads

Comment: So I'm not sure what can be done, aside brute force "tape a cardboard rectange paper to monitor"

Comment: You can always use [the method in this answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286430) to handle it. SE typically has no real issue with things like plugins and user styles to hide specific content.

Comment: @Coffee: Adblock can hide static inline elements as well as blocking iframes and other such third-party content.  It won't save you the trouble of downloading them, of course, but that's not what OP wants.

Comment: Many good methods of hiding the Hot Network Questions in the answers here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222721/134729

Comment: @JonSchneider Thank you. [Your link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222721/134729) now gives instructions and a link for turning this off in preferences.