# The UI is very cluttered. Could the teenagers clean up their bedrooms, please

Tags: feature-request, design, user-interface, user-experience

[edit] the [dupe solved the left side bar](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369106/how-do-i-hide-the-left-navigation-sidebar), thanks for that!

The rest of the space is still cluttered by redundant and useless stuff (as in the same info shown every single time, smack in our face), and the `unanswered` button still stepping on the meta block!

This is hurting, could it be cleaned up a bit?

(even the `unanswered` button is laid over the meta block!?!)

[image]

Maybe to something a tad more zen, like this:

[image]

Comment: Just use an extension to add custom CSS?

Comment: When it reaches this level, clutter is no longer a matter of opinion! @VTC

Comment: @ReblochonMasque It really is, though. I see no issue with how it's laid out.

Comment: "just" @jhpratt ? maybe it is a good idea, how would you do that?

Comment: What size monitor are you using?  How wide/narrow is your browser window?

Comment: 1920 px wide; browser roughly half @Makoto

Comment: I suspect the site design has to adapt to many, partially contradictory expectations by the SE, this might be the reason, why we see so many compromises in it. However, a simple UserCss could solve the problem (maybe even a repository could be useful where we could collect and share our css improvements tuned to our own flavor). I personally use it from a Firefox with a basic adblocker, I never found it harming. I have no idea, how the SE looks for newbies or google visitors, or with an adblocker turned off; but fortunately I don't even need to check it.

Comment: Given the fact that currently sits at +1/-18, I think that answers what the community is looking for. An extensions that lets you add custom CSS should suffice.

Comment: I have to say that I find it hard, to say the least, to replicate the screenshot in this question. [At that resolution you mention, the right-sidebar goes down to the bottom, and the nav-bar works as intended](https://imgur.com/a/s8RhXxT). The tone of your message doesn't help your request, though.

Comment: @jhpratt The downvotes could also primarily be because of the tone. [The post about hiding the left navigation bar](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369106/how-do-i-hide-the-left-navigation-sidebar) got over 300 upvotes. There's also [a post about hiding some stuff from the community bulletin](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251920/provide-a-setting-to-hide-meta-posts-in-the-community-bulletin), which got plenty of upvotes. I'm sure there's also a post around here somewhere about not showing the tag excerpt.

Comment: LOL @yivi, are you implying the screenshot I posted did not happen!?

Comment: Not implying anything. Just saying that **I can’t reproduce the issue**. Maybe you could give more details to make it reproducible. Just that.

Comment: oi, the question has been edited. So no need to keep debating it. People didn't like the post. It was a joke that fell flat. Have real life teenagers and it happens to parents all the time  - the old "dad" jokes.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a problem with the info on the right, as that collapses as the screen get smaller.

[image]

[image]

As for the tag info at the top, it does get annoying. It would be good to have an option to hide/toggle it.

[image]

As a side note:

I have found off things happen with the UI from using scripts. Elements will overlay others. Disable any scripts first and see if the problem persists.